# How to have local package override default package

Tags: installing, texinputs

I have an non-root account on a shared server which has an old version of a package available to all users, and I want to use a newer one on my account. I cannot just use $TEXINPUTS, because latex finds the shared version first. How can I get latex to use my version?

I.e. how can I get latex to use the first of these two files:

```
/home/fgregg/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/pgf.sty
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

By default, local packages are expected to be in ~/texmf, not ~/share/texmf (they are expected to be in ~/Library/texmf on a Mac). So try putting your new version of the package in ~/texmf/tex.  This directory should be found first when latex searches for packages.

Furthermore, the local texmf needs to follow the TeX Directory Structure: (you don't need to create all of these directories initially, but you do need to put things in the right places when you add new stuff.)

```
  •  bibtex directory    This is where bib files and bst files go
     ⁃  bst directory       Put bst files here
     ⁃  bib directory       Put bib files here 
  •  tex directory       This is where new packages go
     ⁃  latex directory     Put latex packages here
     ⁃  plain directory     Put plain tex files here
     ⁃  xelatex directory   Put xelatex specific packages here
     ⁃  xetex  directory    Put plain xetex files here
     ⁃  context directory   Put context files here
     ⁃  generic directory   Put files that are usable with any TeX flavour here
  •  doc directory
     ⁃  put documentation files from packages installed in the tex directory here.
        Putting the documentation files here allows them to be found by the texdoc  
        system.
```

For example, suppose you have the new package `cool-new-package`.  If it's a latex package, the package will come with (at least) a `.sty` file, and some documentation files (often a `.tex` and `.pdf` version). You would create a directory in `~/texmf/tex/latex` called `cool-new-package` and then put `cool-new-package.sty` there.  You would also create a `cool-new-package` directory in  `~/texmf/doc`  and put the documentation files there.

Note that in a brand new installation, a local `texmf` folder is not created and you will need to create one if one doesn't exist.

If you are using a Mac, I have created a standalone script to create the correct folder structure.  You can get it here:

- [Set up a local texmf folder with all the basic structure (Mac)](https://www.msu.edu/~amunn/latex/make-local-texmf.zip)

The source script is usable on Linux systems too, and is available here:

- [mklocaltxmf.sh source (GitHub)](https://github.com/amunn/make-local-texmf)

Comment: Good answer. You could add an example, "For example, you might have `~/texmf/tex/latex/foo/foo.sty` for a local version of the `foo` package."

Comment: ... and then you need to run `sudo texhash ~/texmf` for the packages to get noticed.

Comment: @Seamus: No, you do *not* need to run `texhash` for user additions ever.  And you certainly wouldn't need to run it with `sudo`.  If that were true, the whole idea of user additions would be invalid, since it would prevent non-administrator accounts from ever managing their own local packages.

Comment: Huh. I'm sure I've had packages not work until I did that... What is texhash doing if not telling TeX where to find your new files?

Comment: TeX uses three variables for the directories: `$TEXMF`, `$TEXMFLOCAL` and `$TEXMFHOME`. For the first two a directory list file `ls-R` is needed which is created by `mktexlsr` or `texhash`. The user directory dosn't use such a file. The search order for files is: document dir - TEXMFHOME - TEXMFLOCAL - TEXMF. For MiKTeX you have other directories. And everything is predefined in `texmf.cnf`

Comment: Good post and great answer, worked like a charm

Comment: @Aku it would be helpful if you can you also accept your original question.

Comment: very helpful, thanks. For me, being unable to find much of what is indicated here, I found this path worked: ~/Library/texlive/2013/texmf-var/tex/latex. I'm not recommending it or anything, just saying.

Comment: @PatrickT That folder is *not* a good substitute for your local `texmf` folder.  For one thing, next year when you update to TeXLive 2014, nothing you have placed in that folder will be accessible to the new distribution.  If you don't have a local `texmf` you can find a script on my web page (see my profile) which will create the folder structure for you.

Comment: @PatrickT To create the structure, open a new Finder window, hit Command-Shift-G; type `~/Library` in the box that appears and click OK; now press Command-Shift-N and name `texmf` the new folder. Then you can add the folder to the Favorites bar for easier access.

Comment: @AlanMunn, I see, well I'll do that then, thanks, I was being lazy and went for the path of least resistance ;-)

Comment: @egreg, thanks, that's very detailed, I have copied the steps into my list of survival tips ... and I thought this sort of gymnastics was only on linux! ;-)

Comment: @PatrickT Depending on the version of Mac OS X, the Library folder in your home can be visible or not. If it's visible, it's really no problem in creating a folder inside it; if it's invisible, the Command-Shift-G trick is invaluable. However, see http://www.macworld.com/article/2057221/how-to-view-the-library-folder-in-mavericks.html

Comment: @egreg, thanks, yes it's invisible and your trick is very useful. I also use XtraFinder, which offers a "View" -> "Show Hidden Items" option, as well as tabs (which have now appeared in the latest release, but I'm still on 10.8.5)

Comment: OMG! Thank you for the app! It was such a hassle. The app worked great.