# LaTeX fails to find my .sty file

Tags: packages, errors

```
! LaTeX Error: File `mypackage.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
```

I am getting the above error message in Ubuntu 10.10. I used this on the Windows machine with MikTeX and it worked fine. I am running TeX Live 2010 on my Ubuntu machine.
I put `mypackage.sty` in a folder called `mypackage` under directory

```
/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should *not* put files into `/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex`.  That directory should be reserved for TeXLive itself.

If you are on a multi-user system, you can put files into `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/`, but if it's just you on your linux machine, it's easier to put them in `~/texmf`.  If you do need them in the `texmf-local` folder you will need to run `sudo mktexlsr` to rebuild the file database. If you put things into `~/texmf` you don't need to do this and your packages will always be found.

See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/how-to-have-local-package-overide-default-package/8359#8359) for more details.

Comment: It could be worth mentioning that for "one-off" packages, it could just be put in the same directory as the `.tex` file.