# LaTeX can't find my .bst file. How do I show it the way?

Tags: installing, paths

My question is nearly identical to that posed in these:

[Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files)

[How to have local package override default package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/how-to-have-local-package-overide-default-package/8359#8359)

[LaTeX fails to find my .sty file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8854/latex-fails-to-find-my-sty-file)

but unfortunately, I've followed the instructions in various ways and LaTeX still doesn't find my `.bst` file UNLESS it is in `./` (the `PWD`).  I've tried 3 approaches:

1. `export TEXINPUTS=.:~/my/path:`  (attempted with both `~` and the full-path)
2. put the file in `~/Library/texmf/`  (I'm on a mac)
3. specified the full path to the `.bst` file in the `\bibliographystyle` command

Any ideas what I'm still doing wrong?  I've tried `texhash` (even though it's not supposed to be necessary) and that also failed.  The fact that it works if I put the file in the same directory as the `.tex` file says it's not a problem with the `.bst`.

Comment: The relevant variable is `BIBINPUTS` (like `TEXINPUTS` doesn't need to be set in the shell); its usual value expects a well structured tree in the "personal area"; so `~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst` is the right place.

Comment: @egreg: Actually it is `BSTINPUTS`, isn't it? AFAIK `BIBINPUTS` is where bibtex/biber look for databases (`.bib`-files).

Comment: @Daniel Yes, it's `BSTINPUTS`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [this archive.org link related to TexShop and Mac](https://web.archive.org/web/20160426013815/http://politics.as.nyu.edu/object/latex_texshop_mac):

**How to Install Style and BiBTeX Style files**

```
Create the following folder ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/misc
Place any style files (*.sty) in this folder.
Create the following folder ~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst
Place any BiBTeX style files (*.bst) in this folder.
```

**Where should I put my bibliographic database files?**

```
Create the following folder ~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib
Place any bibliographic database files (*.bib) in this folder.
```

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have any idea why the "standard" ways of doing this do not work?  i.e., why does TexShop (apparently) fail to respect TEXINPUTS?

Comment: Don't know for sure, but I think it not TeXShop. TeXShop just calls `latex` and 'bibtex` and its those programs that need to be able to locate the files. So, if `bibtex` does not use the `TEXINPUTS` path for search, there is not much TeXShop can do about it.

Comment: hmm, ok, but it looks like latex, not just bibtex, is looking in the wrong spots.  If it's not just TeXShop, I wonder why other Mac users seem not to have had the same issue I did?  Or perhaps they did and I've just been reading nix/windows users' posts

Comment: @keflavich: Have you tried setting the variables in a bash shell and then start TexShop from there? Also note that the right variable to set here is `BSTINPUTS`, not `TEXINPUTS`, which might also be the reason TexShop apparently does not respect it (see comments on the question above).