# Where do I put .bst files

Tags: bibtex

I am sorry but I really not an expert with with LaTeX.

I know that there are several posts about it, I tried to follow many of them but I still have no results. I have Windows OS and I am using TeXworks, compiling with command `pdflatex+makeindex+bibtex`. I want to use the `hieeetr` style for the bibliography, but I do not know where to save the `.bst` file. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you read [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files) It is almost the same answer. Instead of `~/texmf/tex/latex`, `.bst` files should go in `~/texmf/bibtex/bst`.

Comment: [LaTeX can't find my .bst file. How do I show it the way?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31865/latex-cant-find-my-bst-file-how-do-i-show-it-the-way) should also be helpful. The answer is for a Mac, but it's the same answer. Instead of the initial part of the file path being `~/Library/texmf/` it will be something like `C:/Users/YOURUSERNAME/texmf`, I think.

Comment: Or I guess it will be `C:\Documents and Settings\<user name>\ ` if you're running Windows XP. Joseph Wright's [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1167/32888) shows file paths for all major operating systems. Just replace all the `/tex/latex/local/`'s with `/bibtex/bst/`'s.

Answer (score 1):

You should put it somewhere in your local-texmf root (if you use TeX Live, you already have one; if you use MiKTeX, create one if not already done with `MiKTeX Settings` application).

More precisely, you should put it in:

```
local-texmf\bibtex\bst\
```

or even in

```
local-texmf\bibtex\bst\ieeetran
```

since it is an extension to the IEEEtran bibtex style, then refresh the filename data base.

But you also might consider using the `biblatex-ieee` package: the job of hieeetr is adding the `eprint` field to ieeetran bibtex style file – and this field is already defined in  `biblatex`.

*Added:*
As pointed by @cfr, after the file(s) have been placed in the relevant place(s), you must refresh the FNDB (MiKTeX, with MiKTeX Settings), or run  `mktexlsr  $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL)`(TeX Live).

Comment: Why a system-wide installation? Why not TEXMFHOME (in the case of TeX Live - no idea about MikTeX)? Using the local tree in TL means updating the filename database as well, else the file won't be found.

Comment: @cfr: I usually install packages for all users, except really private packages. Of course it's a personal choice.

Comment: I tend to do the same but then `mktexlsr $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL)` is required on TL i.e. it isn't enough to just put the file in the right place.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know that (I use MiKTeX). I thought things were more automated on TeX Live than on MiKTeX. I'll add that. Thanks for the information!

Comment: For `TEXMFHOME`, you don't need it because the disk is searched rather than a database. But for `TEXMFLOCAL`, you do. I had the impression that MikTeX was *more* automated - probably because it can install things on-the-fly ;).