# Add bst file with LaTeX / MiKTeX

Tags: bibtex, lyx, miktex

I'm trying to use elsarticle-num-ident.bst, an exact copy of

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\bibtex\bst\elsarticle\elsarticle-num.bst
```

but every time I run LyX, I get the bibtex error

```
I couldn't open style file elsarticle-num-ident.bst
```

This is despite reconfiguring LyX and restarting, and despite running MixTex's Settings/Options' "Refresh FNDB" as Administrator.  It also doesn't work if I put the .bst file in the same folder as the .lyx file.

How should I help lyx/bibtex/Mixtex find the .bst file?

Once I get the identical copy to work, I plan to edit it to not print URLs, as suggested [by mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50960/23423).

Related questions:

- [Where do I put .BST files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170183/where-do-i-put-bst-files)
- [LaTeX can't find my .bst file. How do I show it the way?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31865/latex-cant-find-my-bst-file-how-do-i-show-it-the-way)

Answer (score 4):

You should create a `LocalTeXMF` root directory, say in your personal directory. Whatever the exact name you give it, you have to declare it via `MiKTeX Options`, `Roots` tab, `Add` button. Everything you'll put in this directory must respect the TeX Directory Structure (`TDS`).

In this root, copy the .bst file as `\LocalTeXMF\bibtex\bst\elsarticle\elsarticle-num-ident.bst`, then refresh the FNDB. That's all.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be in the main root?

Comment: It could be overwritten or deleted on updates. As a rule of thumb, one should separate the main root, that is part of the distribution, and personal/local roots. TeX Live creates one automatically, with MiKTeX, you have to do it by yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to make it a subdirectory of my LyX file, which should also help with portability of that document.

Answer (score 0):

My error was that I wasn't using an EXACT copy of elsarticle-num.bst.  I was using the one I downloaded from [Elsevier](http://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/the-journal-document-class-elsart).  Using an exact copy fixed my problem.

Comment: You shouldn't put it the main Root directory, as I explain in my answer.