# bst file not found

Tags: bibtex

I have a llncs document (Springer Lecture Notes in Computer Science) which requires a bibliography style splncs04. However, I get the error message "Style 'splncs04' not found". I have read and tried to implement these questions

[LaTeX can't find my .bst file. How do I show it the way?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31865/latex-cant-find-my-bst-file-how-do-i-show-it-the-way)

and

[Where do I put .bst files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170183/where-do-i-put-bst-files)

but although I tried putting the bst file both in the tex file folder and in `~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst` it gave the same message. Here is my MWE (tex document)

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=splncs04]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Birkhoff}

\begin{document}

~\cite{TarskiGeometryAFP}

 \printbibliography

 \end{document}
```

and bib file

```
@article{Tarskis_Geometry-AFP,
  author  = {T. J. M. Makarios},
  title   = {The independence of Tarski's Euclidean axiom},
  journal = {Archive of Formal Proofs},
  month   = oct,
  year    = 2012,
  note    = {Formal proof development: \url{http://isa- 
  afp.org/entries/Tarskis_Geometry.shtml}. Thesis: 
  \url{http://hdl.handle.net/10063/2315}},
  ISSN    = {2150-914x},
}
```

Comment: You are loading `biblatex`. `biblatex` has its own format for bibliography styles and is not compatible with the `.bst` files used by classical BibTeX. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864 for a bit of background on what `biblatex` is. If you want to use a `.bst` file you must drop `biblatex` and return to the BibTeX way of creating bibliographies. Basically follow https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864 in reverse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are loading the `biblatex` package. `biblatex` is a reimplementation of the BibTeX bibliography system and uses its own system to style the bibliography and citations. In particular does not use `.bst` files to control the output of citations and the bibliography. That means that **you can't use `.bst` files with `biblatex`**. See also [Biblatex induced headache: Bibliography bst style not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61956/35864).

If you want to use `splncs04.bst` you must go back to the BibTeX way of creating bibliographies. You'll essentially have to follow [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864) in reverse:

- Drop `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}`.
- Replace `\addbibresource{<bibfile>.bib}` with `\bibliography{<bibfile>}` and move it to where `\printbibliography` is. (`\bibliography{<bibfile>}` will print the bibliography list.)
- Remove `\printbibliography`.
- Add `\bibliographystyle{<BibTeX style>}` to your document. (It doesn't matter where you put that line as long as there is only one `\bibliographystyle` in your document. Often people put it next to the `\bibliography` to keep both bibliography commands together, but one might feel that `\bibliographystyle` is more appropriate in the preamble.)
- With `biblatex` you probably used Biber as backend and you may have configured your editor to run Biber instead of BibTeX. You will have to make sure to run BibTeX. Essentially you need to follow [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) in reverse.
- One last note: It is a good idea to delete all temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`) after your switch back to BibTeX. Some `biblatex` commands may remain in those files and could cause issues on the next run. The files are recreated on a full LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX run, so deleting them is safe.

you'd end up with something looking like

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\bibliographystyle{splncs04}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum~\cite{TarskiGeometryAFP}

\bibliography{Birkhoff}
\end{document}
```

The only version of `splnc04.bst` that I could find online claims not to need any additional packages like `cite` or `natbib`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked :)