# Problem adding bibliography to llncs paper

Tags: biblatex, overleaf, lncs

I am trying to add my references and bibliography to a paper I am writing in the LNCS format. I have all my references in a file `bibliography.bib` which is in the same folder as all other relevant files. I followed the instruction on the `splncs04.bst` file and I added at the bottom of my paper the following lines:

```
\bibliographystyle{splncs04}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

But my bibliography itself does not appear. Instead I just get "bibliography.bib" on the bottom of the page.

I am using overleaf (the newest version).

Comment: You can not use `biblatex` with `.bst` styles such as `splncs04`. The LNCS template wants you to use standard BibTeX with `splncs04.bst`. Do not load `biblatex` and replace `\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}` with `\bibliography{bibliography}`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432102/35864

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do:

```
\bibliography{bibliography}  % without ".bib"
\bibliographystyle{splncs04} % or whatever style you need
```

Comment: Please explain your answer a bit more!

Comment: I can't explain it but it works.