# Is there a way to automate everything except math mode?

Tags: editors

I'm a math student, and I enjoy using LaTeX (god help me if I typeset that wrong) commands to write mathematical formulae. I'll also be needing it very soon to write papers.

The thing is, though, and this is especially true when I'm writing for pleasure rather than work, when I sit down to write something, I don't want to be staring at this:

[image]

I don't want 90% of the stuff on the screen to be typesetting commands - I want 99% of it to be my actual content. On the other hand, I loathe writing math in WYSIWYG editors, so I'd like my math mode stuff to be entirely hand-coded.

Basically, I'd like a desktop version of the math.SE editor.

Is there a way I can use LaTeX that will essentially handle everything *except* math for me, and just let me write the math manually by typing in dollar signs?

Note that I'm not necessarily asking for an editor recommendation - Texmaker seems nice enough. I'd be happy with maybe some sort of template system? Like I could have the boilerplate code in one file, and have it reference an external file, where I'd just type up the content. Something like that? I'm very new to LaTeX and have no idea what features are commonly available.

Comment: I bever tried it myself therefore I'm not 100% sure, but you could have a look at [`Lyx`](http://www.lyx.org/).

Comment: You can easily do `\input{header.tex}\begin{document}...\end{document}` where `header.tex` contains all your preamble stuff. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, @BenediktBauer, only saw your comment after answering.

Comment: Does this relate to your problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40144/how-to-use-inputfile-tex-correctly/40146#40146

Comment: @zeroth Yes, in that it taught me \input exists, thanks.

Comment: You could use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) and a nice text editor . . .

Comment: @zeroth you could also do `\documentclass{article} ... \begin{document}input{body.tex}\end{document}` and then have a `body.tex` without any "markup".

Comment: @DanielE.Shub Any way to compile that in Texmaker without tabbing back to the root document?

Comment: @DanielE.Shub sure, it was more because it didn't seem like the OP knew the `\input` macro which can do a lot of simplifications. :)

Comment: @JackM in texmaker you can set "master document" and then you don't need to tab back. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest using LyX if you want a more WYSIWYG environment. Used it in the days before I discovered emacs.

[image: Lyx Preview]

For more screenshots head over to [LyX screenshots](http://www.lyx.org/Screenshots)

Comment: LyX is WYSIWYG for math as well - I don't want to have to go into a menu to insert a formula, I just want to wrap it in dollar signs. Is there a way to switch LyX to "manual"?

Comment: I'm trying to think where I saw something similar, but I think a particular emacs preview mode did exactly the opposite, does WYSIWYG for math and not for everything else. When I have a bit of time I'll install LyX and see if I can figure something out.

Comment: @JackM: Actually, Lyx really might be what you are looking for. The math editor also lets you insert the formula as TeX  commands; to insert a formula just press Ctrl+M. No need to go into any menu. You can even define your own math commands.

Comment: @Daniel Is there a way to type in latex commands manually after hitting Ctrl+M? By default LyX renders the commands in real time, which occasionally causes off bugs. The ideal would be to type it in manually, and then they render once I leave math mode.

Comment: @JackM: I am not aware of such feature. However, I do very rarely maths, so there might be a settings trick I am not aware of. I suggest asking this at the `lyx-users` mailing list, where many of the LyX developers hang around and one usually gets a competent answer within a day.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to create two `tex` files. Originally I started with one called `header.tex` and the other called `mydoc.tex`. For `header.tex` the document looked like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
...
```

and `mydoc.tex` looked like

```
\input{header.tex}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor ...
\end{document}
```

I could then run the standard compile rules built into my editor of choice. I then realized I could go even further and switched to a file call `main.tex` and the other called `body.tex`. For `main.tex` it might look like

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{body.tex}
\end{document}
```

and for `body.tex` it might look like

```
Lorem ipsum dolor ...
```

I use `kile` and have written a custom compile rule that compiles `main.tex` no matter what file the current tab is on. Presumably you can do the same with `texmaker`.

Comment: I'd just like to say that I now use this method, but I use one file per section and possibly even one per proof, if it's a long proof.