# Documents in different directories calling the same .sty files

Tags: packages, paths

Suppose I have one folder (folder name: **stys**) where I stored the following files:

- **main.sty**
- **other.sty**

The full path for the **stys** folder is:

```
D:\a\b\c\stys
```

I created one document (**doc1.tex**) which I stored in the following directory

```
D:\a\b\c\daaa
```

**doc1.tex** requires **main.sty**, so I used the following line of code, given their relative paths, to call it:

```
\usepackage{../stys/main}
```

So far, no problems. 
Then, I need **main.sty** to call **other.sty**. I would think that since **main.sty** and **other.sty** are in the same folder, the command for calling **other.sty** would be simply:

```
\usepackage{other}
```

But I quickly found that even though both **.sty** files are in the same directory the command I need is:

```
\usepackage{../stys/other}
```

because **doc1.tex** is calling **main.sty** so the "current directory" is the one where **doc1.tex** is stored.

My problem arises when I start working on a new document, **doc2.tex**, which is stored in a different path:

```
D:\a\b\c\dbbb\e
```

I want to call the same **main.sty** file, which as I said before calls **other.sty**

The problem is that the line of code inside **main.sty** that works for calling **other.sty** for **doc1.tex**, which was:

```
\usepackage{../stys/other}
```

does not work (*File `../stys/other.sty' not found.*) for **doc2.tex** because the path of **other.sty** relatively to **doc2.tex** would be:

```
../../stys/other
```

What is the clever way to make this work without having to change the line where **other.sty** is called inside **main.sty** every time I create a new document in a different directory? (I want to have **main.sty** stored in a single location so that is easy to customize it to my needs over time).

Cheers,

Fabio

Comment: The best way (in my point of view) is to keep all personal `.sty` files in one folder and use the system enviroment variable `TEXINPUTS` point to that folder. However, you use Windows, there might be something similar.

Answer (score 1):

All your personnal configuration files should go in one directory :

/home/myself/texmf/tex/latex/Perso

remplace /home/myself by some other path depending of your OS and latex distribution. Then run some program to make your files known and referenced by the latex distribution (mktexlsr for me). Once the file is knows, you can modify it without running this program, and it is visible from every where you want compile a tex file.

TEXIMPUTS variable is not for this purpose.

Comment: You do not need to run `mktexlsr` if you place the files in TEXMFHOME and are using TeX Live, at least. TeX does not use a filename database in that case - the default setting is to search the disk. If using TeX Live, use `kpsewhich --var TEXMFHOME` to get the correct `texmf` root for installation.