# Collecting Beamer frames from multiple tex files

Tags: beamer, scripts

I now have several dozens of `beamer` TeX files with hundreds of slides. I am wondering is there an easy way of collecting all frames into one document? I think it can be done with any of the scripting languages, or Python, but does anyone know of a TeX-based program than can do this by specifying the directories to search?

The reason is that I am now wasting a lot of time searching old files for slides I know I have already prepared. So if they are all in one pdf I can quickly scan the frames to find the ones I need.

To be specific - I want to extract all `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}` text across hundreds of files to go into 1 TeX file.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7653/how-to-iterate-through-the-name-of-files-in-a-folder) and the [standalone package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone), it's a start at least. With the standalone package, you can insert all frames (and ignore the preamble). I haven't used it in beamer though but it's possible according to the documentation

Comment: You could divide all your presentations into multiple files. One file with the preamble and another one with the actual content. Then `\input` the content into the file with the preamble or use `\input` multiple times for all your content `tex` files to get a presentation with all the frames in it. [Information on `\input`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40144/how-to-use-inputfile-tex-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join all pdfs into one large pdf, you can use `pdfpages` package:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-]{path to first file/first file}
\includepdf[pages=-]{path to second file/second file}
...

\end{document}
```

Comment: This would be OK for a small number of files, but I had a few hundred tex files. I ended up writing a bash script that looped through all the files and extracted everything between the begin doc and end doc tags, dumped it into a new file and added the preamble.

Comment: @icenov You could also do a bash script which writes the list of `\includepdf` commands without filtering the contents between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.