# Do not understand \input

Tags: xetex

This may seem like a very stupid question, but I can't work out how to identify a file to be inputed using `\input` in xelatex. I think I am doing the right thing, but for some reason it does not work.

My main file looks like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\input(testinput.tex)
\end{document}
```

I have a file called `testinput.tex` in the same directory. If, in that directory, I run `xelatex` it complains it cannot find the file, but runs fine if I type in the file's name.

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./test.aux)
! I can't find file `(testinput.tex)'.
l.3 \input(testinput.tex)

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name: testinput.tex
(./testinput.tex) [1] (./test.aux) )
Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

I am baffled as to what I am doing wrong. I have tried this without the `.tex` extension and seen the same result.

Comment: Maybe worth reading: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40144/124577

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your input suggests you use parentheses (`()`) around your file name. The correct way to pass an argument (mandatory) to a LaTeX command is to use braces (`{}`). So you should use the following code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\input{testinput.tex}
\end{document}
```

This is by the way independent of any engine.

*Update:* As LaTeX will automatically append `.tex` you could also use the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\input{testinput}
\end{document}
```

But be aware that here LaTeX will check for file `testinput` first and then look at `testinput.tex`. That's probably a good reason to use the extension `.tex` while inputting the file.

Comment: AFAIK LaTeX does not append `.tex`, TeX itself or `kpathsea` may append `.tex`, but this is implementation depending (nevertheless common for current TeX implementations). LaTeX appends `.tex` only if you use `\include`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke At least for me it works, but you're right though (read it at `weinelt.de`, `golatex.de` says something different).

Comment: @TeXnician: From weinelt.de: "Die Beschreibung auf dieser Seite basiert auf der heutzutage geradezu antiken LaTeX-Version 2.09; die Erweiterungen der aktuellen Version LaTeX2e sind leider immernoch nicht enthalten." ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Haven't seen it at that point.

Comment: @TeXnician: The problem with `weinelt.de` is that this site pops up very frequently if you use Google to look up for `LaTeX reference`. More weird is that the owner of the site started to provide a LaTeX reference with LaTeX 2.09 about 5 years after LaTeX2e was established ...

Comment: I am afraid I cannot read or understand German, so I am not sure what that actually says.

Comment: @TeXnician - thanks it was a stupid mistake that I couldn't follow, but clearing up the rules on appending `.tex` is useful too.

Comment: @Schweinebacke no, adding .tex is implemented by tex-the-program, (and documented in the texbook) it isn't a latex feature.