# Removing slide numbers in the Madrid theme

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I use the Madrid theme.

I would like to know how to remove the slide number and the total number of slides from ALL
slides in my presentation.

Answer (score 8):

Lockstep's answer shows you how to do this on a per-document basis.  If you're likely to be using this a lot, here's how to make the change usable by other documents.

Here's a modified version of the `infolines` outer theme (which is loaded by Madrid) that removes the slide numbering.

### beamerouterthemenoslidenum.sty

```
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{noslidenum theme}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
```

Save this file as `beamerouterthemenoslidenum.sty` somewhere where your document can find it.  If this is for only one document, you could put it in the same folder as the document itself, but a more sensible place to put it would be in your local `texmf` folder where it can be used by other documents too.  If you do that it should ideally go in `<path-to-your-local-texmf>/tex/latex/beamer`

Then in your document, you load the Madrid theme and then load your new outertheme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme{noslidenum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{First slide}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I have tried the above but TeXLive2012 does not find the beamerouterthemenoslides.sty eventhough it is in the same directory as the other outerthemes. Does something need to be refreshed or is the style file in the wrong place? I have put it in the local Texmf directory but still not finding it...

Comment: Forgot to mention when I compile the above file and it says can't find the bemaerouterthemenoslidenum.sty (typo in 1st comment!) i input the location of the style file and it compiles correctly. However, I need to do this each time. What should I do to make TeX find the style files? Using Mac OSX.

Comment: @Leeser You shouldn't put the file in "the same place as the other outerthemes" since that is modifying your TeX distribution. It's best to put local beamer additions on a Mac  in `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/beamer`. If you don't have such a directory, you can use [this script](https://www.msu.edu/~amunn/latex/make-local-texmf.zip) to create the basic structure.  See [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10252/2693).

Comment: Thank you style file placed in local system as directed above. All working as expected. Much appreciated

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
%    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} % DELETED
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\author{(Author)}
\title{(Title)}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}{(Frame title)}
Some text.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Starting with beamer v. 3.49 you can easily remove the frame numbers by using `\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}` after your theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{First slide}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Any clue how to figure out what beamer version I'm using?

Comment: @Andy https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13305/112709