# Installing new style packages on a Mac

Tags: packages, installing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10252/how-do-i-add-a-sty-file-to-my-mactex-texshop-installation)

I am using a mac and want to install the acm style. where do i add the downloaded packages so that tex can find it because i have got multiple tex application running on my system.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Please let us know if the linked question covers your issue- if not, please let us know how it is different :)

Answer (score 4):

If you did a standard installation of MacTeX, local packages can be located in the directory `~/Library/texmf/`. You can install extra packages there, for LaTeX packages use the `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/`.

A  useful application to manage your packages and TeX (Live) installation is [TeX Live Utility](http://mactlmgr.googlecode.com/)

Comment: MacTeX does not create a local `texmf` folder itself, so if you don't have one you need to create it. In the linked duplicate I have a link to a script to create the folder structure on OS X.