# How to make unavailable document classes available for LyX on Macbook?

Tags: lyx, document-classes, lyx-layouts

I have a problem with making unavailable document classes available for LyX on Mac OS X. I have installed LyX and MacTeX (latest versions). I can see the `nature` class in `TeX information` of LyX, but when I go to

> LyX > Document Setting > Local Layout > Library > TeX > Root > `texmf-dist` > TeX > LaTeX > nature

I can see the `nature.cls` there but it looks like hidden files and cannot select it to make it active. I have checked this for available classes also, those are hidden too but they are working. I am confused now. May someone guide me on this please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you are confusing LyX `layout` files and LaTeX `class` files. `nature.cls` is a LaTeX `class` file, but LyX may not necessarily understand it out-of-the-box. LyX needs a `layout` file which acts as a bridge between LyX and the LaTeX `class` file. If LyX has a `nature.layout` (I'm not sure that it does), then all you need to do is install `nature.cls` for your LaTeX distribution, then in LyX do `Tools > Reconfigure` and restart LyX. Now LyX will be aware of the new LaTeX class.

If LyX has no `nature.layout` (I would suggest that you post this query on `lyx-users`), then it might be straightforward to come up with a layout file yourself. See `LyX > Help > Customization > Sections 5.1 and 5.2`.

Lastly, check the following question for simple step-by-step instructions to coming up with a new layout for LyX:

- [How to install an unavailable document class for LyX on Mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84918/how-to-install-an-unavailable-document-class-for-lyx-on-mac)