# Accessing UNAVAILABLE packages in Lyx

Tags: lyx, packages

Will there ever be a quick and simple path to making UNAVAILABLE packages in Lyx available? We've tried all the suggested tips and tricks, all to no avail (literally).

Comment: Sounds a bit paradox. How can something unavailable be available?

Comment: Stop using LyX?

Comment: Do you use MiKTeX or Texlive (or something else)?

Comment: Sarcasm is always helpful.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't help it. Seriously though, it's not very difficult to use LaTeX without LyX, and doing so will probably save you a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: What "LyX packages"?  The  *.deb files to install the program ?  May be the modules or the document classes?  Can you elaborate a bit more the question? It  is unclear what are you asking for

Comment: @IanThompson You have it the wrong way round. After the easiest stuff, LyX is *more* complex to use than LaTeX because you end up needing to know the quirks of both, but it saves you time in the long run. (I used LaTeX for years before using LyX.)

Comment: We're looking to activate the now UNAVAILABLE Springer Verlag monograph package that installs under LaTex but which should in theory also work in Lyx. Thanks!

Comment: When I looked at a .lyx file in a plain text editor I concluded that LyX is not designed to be compatible with LaTeX as even simple things like `\section` are not the same.  So I don't think that you will ever have a quick and simple path, unless the LyX developers aim to make their program code compatible, which I don't think is happening anytime soon.

Comment: seems like you have package confused with class or layout... if you want to have an unavailable layout become available you need to install the *.sty. check this out: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133986/how-to-make-unavailable-document-classes-available-for-lyx-on-macbook