# Problem with footnote in Title and author enviroment

Tags: lyx, footnotes, templates

i am trying to write a paper using LyX instead of latex directly. i have to use the mnras (Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society) template. Since this template is not supported natively by Lyx, i followed the instructions in the website  to add it as a new class. ([How to install an unavailable document class for LyX on Mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84918/how-to-install-an-unavailable-document-class-for-lyx-on-mac)).
so far i didn't have any problem, but now i am trying to add a footnote in the author part of the paper (to include my email) but it does not show. if i do that in a normal paragraph, the footnote appears and all work fine.
i assume the problem is how i added the class in LyX, but i don't know how to fix it. any suggestions?

PD: sorry for my bad english

thanks!

Edit: a code generated with lyx, the only footnote that i can see is the last one.

```
\documentclass[english]{mnras}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{Title\footnote{footnote1}}


\author{Author\thanks{footnote2}}

\maketitle
\author{author \thanks{footnote3}}
\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}

\section{Section 1}

\footnote{footnote4}

The rest
\end{document}
```

Edit2:

The star after the author name appears, but the footnote don't.

Comment: Well, then you should show us a minimal working example, compilable with doccument class, author and tried footnote, ending with `\end{document}`. Then we can copy and compile and test your code ...

Comment: i edited the post to add a minimal working example. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, I do not know class `mnras` and I do not have a documentation of it. You gave no link to the class, but I guess you mean [this one?](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mnras).

If you have a look into the file `mnras.cls` you can find in the definition of command `\maketitle` in the line 1058: `\let\thanks\relax`. That means that this class does not allows command `\thanks` in the title.

**The class you use is very restricted and I suggest to use a standard class, if you have not to submit an paper with that class.**

Anyway, if you use this class you should take a look into the example file and follow the coments (saying: do not change this lines.  That means too: Do **not delete** this lines).

The following MWE compiles with 4 warnings (two because the footnotes, two because the class has to be maintained):

```
\documentclass{mnras}% 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\label{firstpage} % <===================================================
\pagerange{\pageref{firstpage}--\pageref{lastpage}}% <==================
\title[short title]{Title}
\author[K. T. Smith et al.]{
Keith T. Smith,$^{1}$\thanks{E-mail: mn@ras.org.uk (KTS)}
A. N. Other,$^{2}$\thanks{E-mail: Joe@doe.org}
Third Author$^{2,3}$
and Fourth Author$^{3}$
\\
% List of institutions
$^{1}$Royal Astronomical Society, Burlington House, Piccadilly, London W1J 0BQ, UK\\
$^{2}$Department, Institution, Street Address, City Postal Code, Country\\
$^{3}$Another Department, Different Institution, Street Address, City Postal Code, Country
}

%\date{Accepted XXX. Received YYY; in original form ZZZ}
%
%\pubyear{2015}

\maketitle

%\begin{abstract}
%\blindtext
%\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords} % commenting results in missing thanks notes!
keyword1 -- keyword2 -- keyword3
\end{keywords}

\section{Section 1}
This is Text with a footnote\footnote{This is a footnote}

\Blindtext

\Blinddocument

% <============================================ Don't change these lines
%\bsp   % typesetting comment
\label{lastpage}
\end{document}
```

I added the parts you have deleted (see markings `< =======` in the code) and tested a little bit. Theese tests showed me, that you are allowed to omit the abstract, but not the keywords. Comment the environment `keywords` and recompile.  The `\thanks`footnotes disapear.  And the class does not want footnotes in the title.

The result of the MWE above is:

[image: first page of compiled mwe]

The class gives in the header the first and last line (see first red marking). Thats the reason why you are not allowed to delete/change the lines you did.

The other red markings shows the footnotes and their footnotemarks in text and title.

I suggest you call or contact the maintainer of this class or the journal asking you to use this class if you need to use it for your paper.  Report the errors/problems you have and ask for a correction of the class ...

Comment: Call or contact the maintainer to say what exactly? That the class does not permit things which it does not permit? To say that it is claiming it needs maintenance? To say that it doesn't work when you delete bits which it says not to delete? To say that CTAN incorrectly claims it has no maintainer?

Comment: If it is for submission, the journal won't want it changed so the solution is simple: don't change it. In any case, you suggest contacting the maintainer - not the journal. ***If*** the journal wants these changes and this is the class they provide, then contacting them about the problem is appropriate. Otherwise, the changes ought not be made if the paper is for submission, or the changes are not the journal's problem if the paper is not for submission.

Comment: thanks! i will take a look on that file.
PD: the MNRAS allow this kind of footnote in the author part, i dont know why it doesnt work in LyX.