# document class not working properly - strange font

Tags: fonts, lyx, document-classes

I am having a strange problem with the "Document class" option in Lyx. Up until now, all document classes showed as "unavailable". Nonetheless, when I viewed documents as PDFs, they appeared as the standard article class. I wanted to try more document classes, so I read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349952/all-document-classes-installed-with-lyx-are-unavailable-to-use) thread, and followed these steps:

- Copy the files in C:/Program Files (x86)//Resources/layouts/
- Paste the files into C:/Users//AppData/Roaming//layouts/
- In command prompt, run texhash
- Then, in LyX click Tools > Reconfigure; when finished restart LyX.

The document classes now show as available, but something has gone seriously wrong! I have attached a screenshot of how my PDF appears when using the standard article class. The text appears wobbly and nothing like the standard article class that I am used to.

I am using all default settings. Things I have already tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling Lyx
- Updating all packages in MikTex console and reconfiguring Lyx
- Changing to many different document classes

None of these made any difference to the problem. Any advice would be much appreciated! [image]

Comment: Although I cannot answer the question, I see the "all wobbly" text in the image. In general, that is caused when the font outlines do not correspond to some font metrics, or there are bad font hints, or the font (if OpenType) has a bad internal private dictionary. Can you clear the font cache, however that is done for your system, and try again? What engine are you using, and what kind of fonts?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just tried clearing the font cache, and I reconfigured Lyx after (not sure if that is necessary). However the problem persists. Re the type of fonts I am using, I'm not too sure. I just have all default options selected for the standard article class.
p.s. It was font related after all, so thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because reading the OPs own answer it was solved by a change in the Lyx-specific settings.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the `cm-super` package.

Comment: @MS-SPO, this is probably not related to a LyX-specific setting, it is just that this checkbox switch the compiler, and thus the default fonts. The problem is probably with the 8-bit fonts he has on his system.

Comment: @MS-SPO and even if the problem is solved by such setting, I don't see the reason for closing. This site has plenty of questions about LaTeX related software and tools.

Comment: Isaac, can you upload the .log file? you can find it under `Document->LaTeX Log->Open Containing Directory`

Comment: @UdiFogiel, well, I wonder what can be added or done differently to solve the problem? If the answer is "next to nothing", why leaving it open. It still can be found and used. // I stop discussing here.

Comment: @MS-SPO By that argument, any question which is satisfactorily answered or which admits of no satisfactory answer ought to be closed.

Comment: @UdiFogiel is explaining that there **is** more to be done to resolve the problem and that the current 'fix' is only a workaround. Changing a setting in LyX won't fix the font setup.

Comment: @UdiFogiel thanks for your interest. Here is a link to the log file: 
https://filesender.renater.fr/?s=download&token=b471b5ee-478b-4cf7-ade4-b432e633236c

Comment: The log file shows you compiled with XeTeX. Is this the log file of the problematic file or the one that renders properly?

Comment: @UdiFogiel that was the log file for the one that renders properly (after I changed the document settings that I detailed before). Here is the log file for the problematic file, with the original document settings. 
https://filesender.renater.fr/?s=download&token=8596aa12-4490-4ed2-a1a8-b1772d526e9f

Answer (score 1):

Going to the Document tab -> settings -> fonts, and checking the box "Use non-TeX fonts" seemed to solve the problem. Not sure why this is. I suppose I am using non-TeX fonts without meaning to :)

Comment: Well done, Isaac

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem if you want to use pdfLaTeX. You just switched from compiling with pdfTeX, to XeTeX, and XeLaTeX use different fonts by default.