# Question mark in output instead of citation number

Tags: bibliographies

Well it seems I found a treasure consisting of helpful and answering people. So I'll use it.

I plan to use citations in my document. I started with making `thebibliography`. I'll keep it plain simple because I have 9 or 10 references. The code is:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,amsmath,makeidx,cite}
\begin{document}
... By utilizing eye openness along with other facial features \cite{sandbach}.
\begin{thebibliography}{20}
\bibitem{sandbach}
Sandbach, G., Zafeiriou, S., Pantic, M. and Yin, L.:
Static and dynamic 3D facial expression recognition: A comprehensive survey. 
Image and Vision Computing, 2012.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Download of `llncs.cls` under [Springer - Information for LNCS Authors](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0).

My expected output is

```
... facial features [1]
```

but I get

```
... facial features[?]
```

When I hover `\cite{sandbach}` in the `tex` file it shows the correct bibitem entry as I mentioned above. Am I missing something?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Code snippets might be useful but please consider posting a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: See also [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number).

Comment: Your MWE works fine here after some compilation runs! Did you install **all** files of `llcns2e.zip` correctly?

Comment: I formed my `tex` file inside `llncs2e`. I tried to install zip file contents or copy it to package root and couldn't manage to do so in Windows 7 64 bit. And seems I got stuck.

Comment: Personally I'd remove the `\bibitem` and create a dedicated bibtex file using something like jabref or bibtex. This would give me more confidence that the bib file was correctly formatted. Then I'd reference that file from the main .tex file, and compile using the usual latex, latex, bibtex, latex combo. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461905/compiling-latex-bib-source.

Comment: Some probably useful links: [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137) – [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063) – [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10252).