# install a .sty code

Tags: packages, installing

How can I install [this](http://www.latextemplates.com/templates/calendars/1/calendar.sty) code of .sty? I would like to make this calendar, so I need to install it.

Comment: Would this help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10252/how-do-i-add-a-sty-file-to-my-mactex-texshop-installation ?

Comment: @Corentin It refers to Mac OS, but I have Windows.

Comment: You don't _have_ to install it, just putting it in the same folder as your document would work.

Comment: Perhaps this is a better resource: [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it's really helpful. Thank you all.