# I can't get LaTeX to recognize the Venndiagram package even though TeX Live says the package is installed

Tags: errors, packages, installing, texlive, mac

I am new to using LaTeX, I have not figured out how to properly install a package yet. I believe this is my issue, if someone could help guide me through the proper way of doing so I would appreciate it. Even though I grew up with computers, I act like someone one from the 1940's when using them. I know some basic techniques, but a lot of the stuff advanced users might consider trivial is non-trivial to me.

Set up:

- I run a MacBook Pro 2012 with Snow Leopard OS.
- I installed LaTeX using macports on my machine from the terminal. I also downloaded Texmaker editor and use that to write my documents.

Research:

- I looked on this website and it says you should install packages in `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex`. Which I am guessing the `~` = `/Users/<username>`
- I checked my finder and this is all I found; `/Users/Obitus/Library/texlive/2012/texmf-var`

  I also found these:

  `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex`

  `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/tex/latex`

  `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex`
- I can't find the [`venn` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/venndiagram) folder anywhere, but Tex Live Utility says its installed.

Steps I have performed:

- I have installed `texlive-math-extra` package from macports, this is where I originally found the package. It did not work, so I tried installing TeX Live full, which I think a friend of mine did for me a while back.

  I figure the files will overwrite themselves and all will be good, or at least I hoped. Nothing happened, all my previous documents run fine.
- I became a little braver and downloaded `venndiagram.dtx` and `venndiagram.sty` and followed the instructions given to me. I actually got the file to work but only on my desktop. So it only works when I save files on my desktop, not with my TeXmaker editor which saves the files somewhere else.

So now I am I hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You should install [MacTeX](http://tug.org/mactex/); it has a full TeX-Live distribution plus GUI applications for editing etc.  One-stop shopping.  Also, `~` -> your HOME directory i.e., `/Users/Obitus`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Have a look at for **MacTeX distro** [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10252/15717)

Comment: @texenthusiast That answer assume a MacTeX distribution.  The MacPorts version may expect to find things elsewhere, which is probably the cause of the problem.  I agree with Matthew that Obitus should install MacTeX instead of using MacPorts.

Comment: @texenthusiast Alan is saying OP should follow (A) my advice then (B) your advice.

Comment: On Ubuntu TexLive distro, `kpsewhich venndiagram.sty` or `tlmgr info venndiagram` confirms the installation of package.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Should I uninstall all the latex files already there?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: should I uninstall all the latex files already there?

Comment: @Obitus I think the issue is that you have two TeX distributions.  MacPorts typically installs things into `/opt/` doesn't it? So if you have TeXLive in `/usr/local` maybe there's something up with your paths.  It probably wouldn't harm to uninstall the MacPorts altogether, and then install MacTeX.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Ok, that makes sense to me. Yes, Macports installs in /opt/local. I will look up how to uninstall Latex from Macports and all the other Latex files. Then I will install MacTex and let you know if that solves the issues.

Comment: @AlanMunn: I found another post that describes getting rid of "old ports" here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10149/how-to-remove-unused-macports-packages

After successfully following the examples I got rid all the Macports "texlive" ports. Then I downloaded MacTex as suggested, and everything worked out. I can now update my files and post on my math blog.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: Your advice was the best course of action. It worked out great, I can see what you meant by "One-stop shopping".

Comment: Glad to hear it. Sorry I wasn't around to help you through the process. I was AFK.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: Not a problem, everyone helped out excellently. 

Now I am just sitting here updating packages in Tex Live Utility one by one, for some reason the program does not like updating a whole lot of files at once. 

I hope this experience helps someone else out with the same problem.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: Why do you have to wait two days to accept your own answer?

Comment: (Global) StackExchange policy.  I think it's to encourage other answers.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading all the helpful suggestions,the first thing I did was uninstall all the "texlive" ports. I googled "how to uninstall ports in Macports" and found two good websites.

The first one is actual guide to "Macports": http://guide.macports.org/

The second site, which really solved my questions was this one: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10149/how-to-remove-unused-macports-packages

I ran these separate commands in the terminal:

sudo port uninstall vile texlive @2012_0+doc+full

sudo port uninstall inactive

sudo port uninstall leaves

Your "texlive @" might be different, so you will know which one. "Macports" does a good job of telling you if you typed in the wrong one. This is how I found out. It will tell you what ports named "texlive" you have and which one is active.

After I was done uninstalling the old Latex files, I downloaded "MacTex" and installed it. I then opened "Tex Live Utility" and started installing the "Venndiagram" package.

I warn anyone who has "Lion" OS, it was very difficult to install "MacTex" in the first place. It was the reason why I went to on to use "Macports", later on I found a way to put "Snow Leopard" on my machine.