# Use new Beamer theme

Tags: beamer, texlive, texshop, mac, themes

I am sorry for the silly question, but I am new to TexShop and new to Mac as well.
However, I have been looking for a solution in the last two days between the documentation `.pdf` and various forums. This is my last option before going back to PowerPoint.

I have installed TexShop (v. 3.15) from the [TUG website](http://tug.org/mactex/) three days ago.
I want to use a Beamer theme realized by a student from my university.
It consists of three files, an `outer.sty`, a `colorUni.sty` and a `themeUni.sty`.
As I understood, these files have to put in the proper folder.

I think the right location should be this one for the three files:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/color/beamercolorUni.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/outer/beamerouterUni.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/theme/beamerthemeUni.sty
```

(I put the real name of the files here).
Differently from MikTex, I should not update the file database, right?([How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10252/how-do-i-add-a-sty-file-to-my-mactex-texshop-installation))

So, I just open my presentation and call the new theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
 \usetheme{Uni}
}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%title page blablabla
\begin{document}
```

However, I get this message:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/font/beamerfontthem
edefault.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/color/beamercolorth
emedefault.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/inner/beamerinnerth
emedefault.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/outer/beamerouterth
emedefault.sty)))


! LaTeX Error: File `beamerthemeUni.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
Enter file name:
```

If I enter again the path with the `.sty` files, it repeats the same message; if I hit return it gives the presentation with the standard theme.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: It still gives me the same error message with `\usepackage`.

Comment: I tried, but the error message remains.

Comment: `texmf-dist` is the wrong location; please read [the documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-370003.4.6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use exactly the same preamble than yours, but I think you must have your files in a directory with you theme name for each .sty

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/color/Uni/beamercolorUni.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/outer/Uni/beamerouterUni.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/theme/Uni/beamerthemeUni.sty
```

That is what I have on my system.

Comment: Great @penbeuz! 
It worked after three error messages asking for the new path.
Once put it it was fine.

Comment: `texmf-dist` is the wrong location; please read [the documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-370003.4.6).