# Why is the gap between the translation and the last line of the gloss so wide in my interlinear gloss?

Tags: linguistics, gb4e, cgloss4e

I notice if I take away some letters, the translation line goes to where it should be, but this big block of white space is pretty untenable. Ideas?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex
\glll Jichax    Qamaqix lij parki,  aynacha,    amsta,  parki, q'awanaks,   khuyt'asis  sarawjchix. \\
\{jicha-x(a)    Qamaqi-x(a) lij(u)  parki   aynacha amsta   parki q'awa-nak(a)-_{c}$\oslash$-s(a)   khuy(u)-t'a-s(i)-s(a)   sara-wj(a)-ch(i)-i-x(a)\}    \\
now-\textsc{top}    Fox-\textsc{top}    all acclivity   declivity   ascent  acclivity ravine-\textsc{pl-acc-ad} whistle-\textsc{m}-\textsc{refl}-\textsc{subr} go-\textsc{bfr-cnj-3sim-top}\\
\glt `And so, Fox must've gone whistling on all the ascents, slopes, ascents, mountainsides, and even in the ravines.'
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've posted a screenshot of the output. Could you elaborate on what the problem is?

Comment: The tremendous gap between the last line and the translation. If you take out the "R" of "SUBR" in the penultimate line, you'll see that the spacing returns to "normal"...

Comment: Now, I see what the problem is. You should add this explanation to your question.

Comment: this problem has bedeviled me for some time as well. The only fix I have for it is to stick in `\phantom{xx}` into the source language and gloss line to make the spacing come out right.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure what the cause of the problem is, but Alexis Dimitriadis has a modified version of `cgloss4e` called `cgloss.sty` which solves the problem.  Unfortunately Alexis has never put this up on CTAN, but his web space is very stable.

You can get the file here:

http://staticweb.hum.uu.nl/medewerkers/alexis.dimitriadis/latex/

There are various questions on the site about installing style files; pick one that matches the operating system and TeX Distribution you have.

- [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10252/2693)
- [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/2693)

Here's a fixed version. You need to load `cgloss` after loading `gb4e`. I usually put them in the same `\usepackage` command. The modified version also has the nice property of allowing material to be added after the gloss lines (to indicate source language or citation for example.)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{setspace}
\makeatletter
\def\new@fontshape{}% Needed due to changes in LaTeX kernel
\makeatother
\usepackage{gb4e,cgloss}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex
\glll JichaxQamaqix lij parki,  aynacha,amsta,  parki, q'awanaks,   khuyt'asis  sarawjchix. \\
\{jicha-x(a)Qamaqi-x(a) lij(u)  parki   aynacha amsta   parki q'awa-nak(a)-_{c}$\oslash$-s(a)   khuy(u)-t'a-s(i)-s(a)   sara-wj(a)-ch(i)-i-x(a)\}\\
now-\textsc{top}Fox-\textsc{top}all acclivity   declivity   ascent  acclivity ravine-\textsc{pl-acc-ad} whistle-\textsc{m}-\textsc{refl}-\textsc{subr} go-\textsc{bfr-cnj-3sim-top}\\
\glt `And so, Fox must've gone whistling on all the ascents, slopes, ascents, mountainsides, and even in the ravines.’
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]