# Extra space between gloss and translations

Tags: linguistics, gb4e

In some examples in which I have an example (especially a multi-tier one) made in an example environment with gb4e, there's a huge gap between the the \glt line and the one directly above it. This looks terrible on the page. I'm not sure why this happens.

```
\begin{exe} \ex  {\glll  x y z\\  \{ x-acc y-decl z-nom \\ eks why
zee\\}

\sn{\glll a b c. \\  a b c \}\\ ay bee see \\ \glt `Chickens like
catfood, in my pasta factory.' [Garbo-R124-1]} \label{pastafact}
\end{exe}
```

Comment: You have asked this question before: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116203/why-is-the-gap-between-the-translation-and-the-last-line-of-the-gloss-so-wide-in, but haven't accepted or commented on the answer given.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is somewhat messy and some elements of it I don't understand. What is the purpose of the initial and final curly brackets, and what is the purpose of the printed curly brackets `\{` and `\}`?

At any rate, I don't see any "huge gap". I think it looks entirely appropriate - and not terrible at all. Do you not get what I get?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
    \begin{exe}
        \ex
            \glll x y z\\
            x-acc y-decl z-nom\\
            eks why zee\\
        \sn
            \glll a b c\\
            a b c\\
            ay bee see\\
        \glt `Chickens like catfood, in my pasta factory.' [Garbo-R124-1]
    \end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sure, on its own it looks great. But depending on where it comes out in the page, sometimes that spacing very bad.

Comment: @mateuz Then please post a MWE that illustrates your problem.

Comment: It's a ginormous document -- but it happens whenever the example is somewhere in the middle (i.e. not the top or bottom) of the page.

Comment: The ``M`` in MWE stands for ``minimal``, so please post a **minimal** example that illustrates your problem. I see in your history that you have been asked repeatedly to produce such examples, but you never do. You're unlikely to receive much help here if you're reluctant to provide us with MWEs.

Comment: Like I said, I'm working on a manuscript that's like 300 pages long. I could provide a screen shot, but I'm not sure that'd help anyone...

Comment: No, you're not asked to produce your full original document. You're asked to produce a **minimal** working example that will illustrate your problem. Please read the two top answers here: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that