# gb4e leaves extra space before translation

Tags: spacing, linguistics, gb4e

gb4e leaves extra (unwanted) blank line space between gloss and translation. Same problem as here: [Why is the gap between the translation and the last line of the gloss so wide in my interlinear gloss?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116203/2693) but the answer there (`cgloss.sty`) doesn't always fix the problem. In the following code - the third `\glt` line has a wide space before it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[safe]{tipa}

\usepackage{gb4e,cgloss}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
    \ex \gll kma t'-\textschwa{l}\v{c}qu-(\textgamma)in \\
    {\sc 1sg}  {\sc 1sg.sub-}see-{\sc 2sg.obj} \\
    \glt `I saw you.' (S1:71)

    \ex \gll q-\textschwa{l}\v{c}qu-{\textbeta}um kma\\
    {\sc 2.irr-}see-{\sc 1sg.obj} {\sc 1sg}\\
    \glt `Look (at) me.' (S1:75)

    \ex kma t-k'o{\textbeltl}-ki\v{c}en \\
    {\sc 1sg} {\sc 1sg.subj-}come-{\sc 1sg.subj} \\
    \glt `I came/arrived.' (S3:13)

\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I took the liberty to change the deprecated ``\sc`` with ``\textsc`` and clean up the code a bit.

Comment: @Sverre Honestly I don't think that kind of change is appropriate.  Maybe a comment about such commands being deprecated, but changing the code in a question is IMO, not really a good idea.

Comment: @AlanMunn Feel free to roll back my edit if I stepped out of line. My intention was to prevent comments and answers pointing out these things rather than the problem at hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in a typo in your last example: you forgot the `\gll` line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[safe]{tipa}
\makeatletter
\def\new@fontshape{}% Needed due to changes in LaTeX kernel
\makeatother

\usepackage{gb4e,cgloss}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
    \ex \gll kma t'-\textschwa{l}\v{c}qu-(\textgamma)in \\
    {\sc 1sg}  {\sc 1sg.sub-}see-{\sc 2sg.obj} \\
    \glt `I saw you.' (S1:71)

    \ex \gll q-\textschwa{l}\v{c}qu-{\textbeta}um kma\\
    {\sc 2.irr-}see-{\sc 1sg.obj} {\sc 1sg}\\
    \glt `Look (at) me.' (S1:75)

    \ex \gll kma t-k'o{\textbeltl}-ki\v{c}en \\
    {\sc 1sg} {\sc 1sg.subj-}come-{\sc 1sg.subj} \\
    \glt `I came/arrived.' (S3:13)

\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

BTW, the two-letter font changing commands (`\bf`, `\it`, `\rm`, `\sc`, etc.) are deprecated and should really not be used.  Instead, it's better to use `\textbf{<foo>}`, `\textit`, `\textrm`, `\textsc` or their switch counterparts (`\bfseries`, `\itshape`, `\rmfamily`, `\scshape`)  See [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/2693).