# Installing eqexam package for use with Sublime Text 2

Tags: installing, texlive, mactex

I am looking to utilize the `eqexam` package, yet even after putting the `.sty` files in my `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex` directory with the appropriate `/eqexam` folder . I am still unable to compile the demo file that came with the package. I have included a `MWE` of the test file below.

I still get the error that `eqexam.sty` not found. I have searched all over the internet for a solution, but no one seems to be in agreement on the answers.

Running Mac OS X 10.6.8, originally used MacTex distribution with TexLive2012, but am now compiling with ST2 and Skim (which has worked wonders over texshop). I could list my suspicions, but that might be a waste of time. I also understand that this might not be enough information to problematize a solution, but I have hopes.

I suppose that there will not be a solution to this, but might there be better resources than the `eqexam` documentation and website that can take me through the complexities of the installation?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[coverpage,forcolorpaper,pointsonboth,totalsonright]{eqexam}
%\usepackage[forcolorpaper,pointsonleft,nosolutions]{eqexam}
% Note, to use this next line, your exerquiz must be up to date with the eqexam you are using
\usepackage[nosolutions,forcolorpaper,pointsonboth,totalsonright,noparttotals]{eqexam}

\title[T1]{Test 1}
\author{D. P. Story}
\subject[C1]{Calculus I}
\date{Spring \the\year}
\keywords{Test~1, Section 001}

\university
{%
      THE UNIVERSITY OF AKRON\\
    Theoretical and Applied Mathematics
}
\email{dpstory@uakron.edu}

\hfuzz = .7pt

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{exam}[Part I.]{Part1}

\begin{instructions}[Part I.]
Solve each of the problems without error. If you make an error,
points will be subtracted from your total score.
\end{instructions}

\begin{problem}[5]
This is an example of a objective question, the student fills in
his/her response in the space below.

\begin{solution}[.5in]
The solution to the question. This solution will not appear when
the option \texttt{nosolutions} is specified. It will appear
immediately after the question with the \texttt{solutionsafter}
option, and appear at the end of the document if a solutions
option is not specified.
\end{solution}
\end{problem}


\begin{problem}[5]
An example of a fill-in question:
It is well known that \fillin{1in}{Newton} and
\fillin{1in}{Leibniz} are jointly credited as the founders of
modern calculus.

\begin{solution}
It is well known that \underbar{Newton} and \underbar{Leibniz} are
jointly credited as the founders of modern calculus.

\medskip\noindent\textbf{Notes.} Here the optional argument for
the \texttt{solution} environment is not specified, this implies
that no room should be left for the student to answer, seems
reasonable since this is a fill-in.
\end{solution}
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you run sudo mktexlsr for changes to take effect? It works for me under Debian.

Comment: Can I run that from any folder, or a specific folder? My terminal outputs this: `sudo: mktexlsr: command not found`

Comment: I'm not sure how it works on OSX but your TeX distro needs to rebuild its database of installed packages. The temporary fix is to put the sty file in your local folder that contains the source Tex files, that should work afaik.

Comment: Check this out: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10252/how-do-i-add-a-sty-file-to-my-mactex-texshop-installation

Comment: That was it! Thanks @aitatanit ! It turns out that the directories my build was looking for didn't even exist. And that I had `/texmf` directories, but not in the correct location. The link and the answer provided worked wonders.

Comment: If an answer is crafted, I believe it should mention that the `/texmf` directory is possibly nonexistent, despite having MacTex installed. This was my exact problem. Sublime Text 2 could not manage the distribution that had been setup for TexShop or TexWorks.