# No available SBL style?

Tags: document-classes

Where can I find a link that actually works for the document class/stye/package Society of Biblical Literature (SBL)? AFAIK all related threads in this forum and elsewhere are either broken or the link to the file is dead.

** UPDATE: SEE MY ANSWER (#2) BELOW FOR A NEW STYLE **

Comment: I googled it within seconds https://github.com/jackweinbender/sbl-latex

Comment: I had visited that resource already. It has important files but all of them require a document class that is not available, for example "rcfsblpaper".

Comment: they are!! document classes end with *.cls. browse to sbl-latex/ Library/texmf/tex/latex/sbl/ in the repository. it is all there. the author put it in the correct tex-tree file structure already

Comment: I am a newbie, sorry for that. The problem is that when I go to Raw and do a cut/paste to Texpad, it does not typeset because it lacks the document class, according to the error message. Don't know what I am doing wrong. What to download and to which directories for it to work?

Comment: Please note that the sbl-latex repo is forked from https://github.com/RobertFischer/sbl-latex and that I really haven't done anything to it.

Comment: @Nhaps -- Download the `.zip` file and then use `\documentclass{sblessay}` or `\documentclass{sblbook}` in your `.tex` file.

Comment: SEE MY ANSWER BELOW. I am very satisfied with the template created by purton, and it is maintained regularly

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the link: [Latex styles for the Society of Biblical Literature Handbook of Style](https://github.com/jackweinbender/sblhs-latex#latex-styles-for-the-society-of-biblical-literature-handbook-of-style) (updated class and style files)
2. Click the `Download Zip` icon on the lower right corner as shown in the image below:
   [image]
3. This will ensure that you have all of the `.cls` files. Open the `sbl-latex-master.zip` file and extract all.
4. Search in the folder: `sbl-latex-master\Library\texmf\tex\latex\sbl`. You should now see all of the class files as shown below:
   [image]
5. To add new style files on MacTeX, see this link: [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10252/10898)

Comment: Thanks very much! I got the zip file, but the readme info says: "Install the given files into those directories, either in the root of your filesystem or relative to your home directory" By home directory is it referring to the 1)MacTex directory or the 2)folder of my choice within the home directory? Can I keep class documents in any folder I want inside home?

Comment: @Nhaps Sure. But it would be nice to include these files in your localtexmf directory for your own custom files. Doing this will enable you to use the class files like any other.

Comment: @Nhaps Remember thought that if you include these in your local texmf (ie under `\texmf\tex\latex\sbl`), you will need to refresh your filename database (fndb). Note also that you will need to  create the directory `\sbl`

Comment: Thanks @Martin H for your kindness in walking me through the process. Situation here is improving. Thanks azetina as well. BTW how do I refresh my filename database?

Comment: One of the contributors from Github, Jack Weinbender, was kind enough to send me an updated URL for SBL class:https://github.com/jackweinbender/sblhs-latex

Comment: @Nhaps See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am in the process of producing an updated template for the SBL Handbook of Style, second edition.

Answer (score 1):

The `sbl-latex` repo on github is owned by Robert Fisher. It uses a `.bst` file to compile the bibliography. it is very sophisticated and outputs really nice documents. I don't think it is still under active development.

https://github.com/RobertFischer/sbl-latex

However, when I wrote my thesis, I found a few things about it that I couldn't change easily, so I looked around and tried to find something a little more flexible for my own purposes. I ended up writing a class that extended the article class with minimal changes and packages. I used the CMS `biblatex` package for the bibliography and rely on `Xelatex` for unicode font support.

https://github.com/jackweinbender/sblhs-latex

`sbl-latex` and `sblhs-latex` are completely unrelated.

I am *not* a developer, but this produced a decent looking thesis for me. Pull requests are welcomed. I'd really like to see others to contribute to this to provide a clean working class/style for SBLHS, particularly since there will likely be an SBLHS revision in the next few years.

Comment: That sbl-latex is no longer under active development is sad. Volunteers like @jackweinbender who post their adjustments to the style are to be commended.

Answer (score 1):

THE QUESTION LED TO THIS NEW TEMPLATE:

David Purton and I (he's the genius behind it) have been actively involved in a brand new BibLaTeX standard template for SBLHS version 2. Progress is ongoing, with optimal results. Check it out at https://github.com/dcpurton/biblatex-sbl

Answer (score 0):

I googled it by looking for the actual name of the class `rcfsblpaper.cls`

[This seems to be the github location now](https://github.com/jackweinbender/sbl-latex)

Answer (score 0):

I am actively developing SBL-paper class from Robert Fischer and am porting biblatex-Chicago for SBLHS2. Contact me for early access