# Where to install .cls and .clo files in texlive 2013?

Tags: texlive

I'm on Mac OS X and have texlive 2013 installed. For a journal paper, I need to install two .cls and .clo files. All the read says is `Copy svjour3.cls and svglov3.clo to a place where LaTeX can find them.`

I dropped these files to

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex
```

and tried to run `texhash` but this is what happens:

```
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: Done.
```

If I try to compile a .tex file that's in the same directory as the .cls and .clo files, it works, but not if the file is somewhere else. So where is the proper place to put this?

Comment: You have to run `texhash` as root. Or you can paste the files in the same folder as your main TeX file.

Comment: To run `texhash` as root use `sudo texhash` from an admin account.  But the standard local `texmf` folder on a Mac is `~/Library/texmf/` and then you don't need `texhash`. See [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10256/2693), which is a duplicate.

Comment: To add cls package (like moderncv) in my OS distribution with **texlive 2015**, I just unzip package under `/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex`. 
Don't forget to run `sudo texhash`!

Hope this help.