# How to draw the cards of a deck?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw the cards from a deck using a Latex package, as TikZ?[image]

Comment: \includegraphics{}

Comment: Excuse me. I know insert a figure. What I want is to learn how to draw using a tool of Latex.

Comment: Whereas the some of the (number) cards could be drawn with `tikz`, `pstricks` etc, especially the cards showing images like King, Queen, Joker, Jake are too complex to draw it with tikz.

Comment: Please review the answers you've got to your other questions and consider accepting the most deserving ones: http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36688/benedito?tab=questions

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: (+1) i seem a reasonable question to ask by a tool to draw *poker cards* in latex.

Comment: You may use [SVG-Cards](http://svg-cards.sourceforge.net/)...

Comment: And finally the accepted answer was the most criticized (first comment), `\includegraphics{}`. Lol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a solution using [`SVG-Cards`](http://svg-cards.sourceforge.net/), [`inkscape`](http://www.inkscape.org/) and `PDFLaTEX/graphicx/TikZ`.

I provide a `Makefile` :

- to download and to extract the SVG-Cards archive (via `wget` and `tar`),
- to extract each SVG card from `svg-cards.svg` (via `inkscape`)
- to convert each SVG card into a PDF card (via `inkscape`)
- to compile `cards.tex` (via `pdflatex`)

Steps:

1. Copy the `Makefile` (*note: the white spaces at beginning of lines are tabulations*) and the `cards.tex` below.
2. Run `make` to get `cards.pdf`

<sup>**Note:** if you can't use this `Makefile`, I provide [cards.tgz](http://perso.mines-albi.fr/~gaborit/latex/cards.tgz). This archive contains all extracted PDF cards (needed to compile `cards.tex`).</sup>

[image]

The `Makefile`:

```
JOKERS = black_joker red_joker
LEVELS = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 jack queen king
CLUBS = ${LEVELS:%=%_club}
DIAMONDS = ${LEVELS:%=%_diamond}
HEARTS = ${LEVELS:%=%_heart}
SPADES = ${LEVELS:%=%_spade}
CARDS = ${CLUBS} ${DIAMONDS} ${HEARTS} ${SPADES} ${JOKERS}
CARDS_PDF = ${CARDS:%=card-%.pdf}

all: cards.pdf

cards.pdf: cards.tex $(CARDS_PDF)
    latexmk -pdf cards.tex

card-%.pdf: card-%.svg
    inkscape --export-pdf=$@ $<

card-%.svg: SVG-cards-2.0.1/svg-cards.svg
    inkscape --export-plain-svg=$@ --export-id=${@:card-%.svg=%} --export-id-only $<

SVG-cards-2.0.1/svg-cards.svg:
    wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/svg-cards/files/SVG-cards-2.0.1.tar.gz
    tar zxvf SVG-cards-2.0.1.tar.gz
```

The `cards.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \col[count=\c] in {spade,heart,diamond,club}{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(\c*90:1.5cm)}]
      \foreach \level[count=\val] in {1,...,10,jack,queen,king}{
        \node[inner sep=0,anchor=south,rotate={40-(\val*6)}]
        at ({140-(\val*6)}:1cm)
        {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{card-\level_\col}};
      }    
    \end{scope}
  }
  \node at (-2,0) {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{card-red_joker}};
  \node at (2,0)  {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{card-black_joker}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this in *Windows* without `cygwin`? That's my work platform.

Comment: @skpblack pdflatex, latexmk and inkscape exist for Windows. You may download manually the SVG-Cards archive then try GnuWin (a gnumake for windows)...

Comment: @skpblack : I added a _note_ with a link to an archive with all PDF cards

Comment: This is such a great contribution. I used it to illustrate a Venn diagram intersection. FYI http://docdro.id/KaJUDjw

Comment: The export-latex function has a bug preventing you to export just one object with a certain ID. It produces and empty page. The trick by just exporting de ID to a plain SVG file and then do the Latex export works around this limitation. Very good, thanks!

Answer (score 24):

The closest solution I found is the *experimental* package [`poker`](http://web.mit.edu/foley/Games/Arcadia/sr/poker/poker-doc.pdf) developed by [*Olaf Encke*](http://encke.net/UpDownload-req-viewsdownload-sid-3.html). This package is based on **PSTricks** (with all complications to run in `pdflatex`) further that this package is not standard and generally is not included in the *Standard TeX Distributions (MaCTeX, TeXLive or MiKTeX)* and it must be *manually* installed.

I recommend these steps:

- Download and extract the package from [MIT webpage](http://web.mit.edu/foley/Games/Arcadia/sr/poker4latex.081.tar.gz).
- Depending of your distribution *Install manually the package*. (For [*MiKTeX*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/) you must [Create a local texmf tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/), if you use a system as **Linux** read [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/), and [read here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10252/) for *MaCTeX*).
- Run using the path `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf`.
- If you need the figures to include in others files `.pdf` (with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`) then clip using

  ```
  pdfcrop --hires <file> <file.pdf>
  ```

### Code Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{poker}
\pagestyle{empty} %No number in pages
\begin{document}

\begin{cards}
\crdAs\crdKh
\end{cards}

\begin{cards}
\crdpair{\crdKs}{\crdtenh}%
\crdflop{\crdsevd}{\crdsevc}{\crdQd}%
\crdKc\crdKd%
\end{cards}

\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Now we have the `pst-poker` package which is included in TeX Live. Its document says "`pst-poker` is based on the package `poker` from Olaf Encke (http://web.mit.edu/ foley/games/Arcadia/sr/poker/pokersty)."

Answer (score 21):

Depends what you want to do with them. If you going to enter them in a paper to describe probabilities etc, better to use a font. As of Unicode 7.0 there are codepoints for card suite. Use the Symbola free font of [George Douros](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\symbola{Symbola.ttf}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\symbola
\char"1F0AB \char"1F0CF
\end{document}
```

Use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

[image]

With a unicode font you can just type "The drawn trump suit from the draw deck is a ♣ card (2♣)." and typeset the text easily.

[image]

Comment: In addition to your answer: [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode) are all possible cards of the unicode, [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f0a1/index.htm) you get closer information on each code, and [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%F0%9F%82%A1+-+PLAYING+CARD+ACE+OF+SPADES+%28U%2B1F0A1%29), you may check which fonts on your system support that symbol.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Thanks for the links. I am aware of some of the other fonts, they are hard to come by (if you see in your link) there only about three other fonts you can use. The `Quivira` is a particularly good one as well, so are the `No Tofu` from Google. The last one is very lightweight and has an advantage if you don't mix it with other text.