# Is there a simple way to typeset playing cards?

Tags: symbols

I'm writing some probability lectures and would like to typeset some playing cards.

I'm aware of the `poker` and `pst-poker` packages, but can't get them to work. Is there a less sophisticated way to typeset playing cards?

Comment: Possibly the fact that it does not work is related to your choice of compiler. E.g. `pdflatex` may not work without further ado for PStricks based packages.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but I'd like a solution compatible with my current latex setup.

Comment: Well, yes, but how would anyone know what your current latex setup is?

Comment: What I mean is, I'm curious if there are other solutions. Whether those other solutions work with my setup will be my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to draw the cards of a deck?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207929/14500).

Answer (score 24):

EDITED to flip-the-pip in the lower right of the card (hat tip Aofl), and to add a club (flower) suit example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,xcolor,rotating}
\newcommand\blackcard[2]{%
  \begingroup\fboxsep=0pt\relax
  \fbox{\tabbedCenterstack{%
  \scriptsize$#2$ && \\&\makebox[10pt]{#1}&\\&
  &\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\scriptsize$#2$}}}%
  \endgroup}
\newcommand\redcard[2]{%
  \begingroup\fboxsep=0pt\relax
  \fbox{\color{red}\tabbedCenterstack{%
  \scriptsize$#2$ && \\&\makebox[10pt]{#1}&\\&&\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\scriptsize$#2$}}}%
  \endgroup}
\begin{document}
\blackcard{Q}{\spadesuit}
\redcard{10}{\heartsuit}
\blackcard{8}{\clubsuit}
\redcard{A}{\diamondsuit}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I thank corporal for stepping in, in my absence, to help with some of the OP's follow-up questions (HOOAH!).  Here, I employ his suggestions, though making some small changes, to account for different glyph widths among the packages.

The Joker I provide gratis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,xcolor,txfonts,fancybox,arev,graphicx}
\cornersize{.1}
\newcommand\blackcard[2]{%
  \begingroup\fboxsep=0pt\relax
  \Ovalbox{\tabbedCenterstack{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\scriptsize$#2$} && \\
    &\makebox[22pt]{#1}&\\
    &&\makebox[0pt][r]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\scriptsize$#2$}}}}%
  \endgroup}
\newcommand\redcard[2]{%
  \begingroup\fboxsep=0pt\relax
  \Ovalbox{\color{red}\tabbedCenterstack{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\scriptsize$#2$} && \\
    &\makebox[22pt]{#1}&\\
    &&\makebox[0pt][r]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\scriptsize$#2$}}}}%
  \endgroup}
\newcommand\jokerface{\raisebox{-2pt}{\kern-1pt\stackengine{0pt}{%
  \stackinset{c}{1pt}{c}{-.4pt}{\stackunder[.7pt]{$\cdot\kern2pt\cdot\kern0.3pt$}%
  {--}}{$\bigcirc$}}{\,$\steaming$}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}}
\newcommand\joker{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{.4}{ \tiny JOKER }}}}
\begin{document}
\blackcard{Q}{\spadesuit}
\redcard{10}{\varheartsuit}
\redcard{A}{\vardiamondsuit}
\blackcard{\jokerface}{\joker}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any chance on rounding off the corners to make it 'prettier'

Comment: @3kstc. One way to obtain rounded corners is to use the `fancybox` package and change `\fbox` to `\Ovalbox` or `\ovalbox,` and use `\cornersize{0.1}`. The `\blackcard` \def becomes `\newcommand\blackcard[2]{%
  \begingroup\fboxsep=0pt\relax
  \cornersize{.1}\Ovalbox{\tabbedCenterstack{%
  \scriptsize$#2$ && \\&\makebox[10pt]{#1}&\\&&\scriptsize$#2$}}%
  \endgroup}`

Comment: And also fill in the heart and diamonds in red to make it consistent with the spades theme.

Comment: @3kstc To fill the hearts and diamonds: `\usepackage{txfonts}` then use `\varheartsuit` and \vardiamondsuit.

Comment: Where's the flower card? :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano What is a "flower card"?  Is that what we call in English, the "Joker"?

Comment: Thank you @corporal

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Sebastiano is referring to "clubs"... They're called *fiori*, flowers, in Italian.

Comment: @Rmano Thanks for the tip. I didn't show it, but I presume `\clubsuit` does the trick.

Answer (score 7):

Run with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-poker}
\begin{document}    
\crdAs \crdtenh \crdsevd \crdsevc \crdQd
\end{document}
```

or with `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-poker}
\begin{document}    
\begin{postscript}
\crdAs \crdtenh \crdsevd \crdsevc \crdQd
\end{postscript}
\end{document}
```

[image]