# How to instal document class type for use in R studio.

Tags: packages, installing

I found a template on writeLaTex.com for optica style articles. I downloaded the optica.cls from the optical website so i could follow that format. Just fooling around to learn more and unfortunately can't get this one at all.

```
      \documentclass[9pt,twocolumn,twoside]{optica}
```

no matter what the following code is, which should be okay because I'm working with a template that I downloaded with the optica.cls zip folder, the error i receive is "Latex error: file 'optical.cls' not found". but its just sitting in downloads.

You should also know that the file is still in my "downloads folder" and i don't know exactly where to place it

After hours of pain and reading i can't seem to figure this one out on my own.

you might also want to know that i am using RStudio on a Mac OS 10.10 as my PDF compiler if that changes anything.

Thanks in advanced for helping out and taking your time to read.

Comment: Try moving it into the directory which contains the document you are trying to typeset.

Comment: yea that worked for that particular project. is there any way to make it permanent?

Comment: `mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/optica` and then move the class file into that directory.

Comment: [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137)

Comment: Or a more Mac oriented duplicate: [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10252/2693)