# Local packages not found on MacTex

Tags: lyx, packages, mactex

I want a package that is not part of the MacTeX distribution.

I'm running Lyx 2.1.1 (on OSX) and want to use `icml2013.sty` I followed [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10252/how-do-i-add-a-sty-file-to-my-mactex-texshop-installation), which said to make local additions to MacTeX in `Library/texmf`. I did this. My package is presumably in the correct place: `Library/texmf/icml2013.sty`

I reconfigured LyX and then created a document with:

```
\usepackage[accepted]{icml2013}
```

When I try to view the document, I get an error:

> LaTeX error: File 'icml2013.sty' not found.

Where does the package need to be (e.g., a sub-directory of `Library/texmf/`)? Or this is a problem with MacTeX?

Comment: it should be in texmf/tex/latex/icml/icml2013.sty or just put it in the same folder/directory as your document that would also work

Comment: The detail here is closed in the answer I've linked (duped) to: I see @DavidCarlisle has already covered the core part in a comment!