# Default to Single Window Mode in TeXShop

Tags: editors, texshop, mac

Is there a way to ensure that TeXShop always opens in single window mode?

EDIT: I've been asked to explain how this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10252/how-do-i-add-a-sty-file-to-my-mactex-texshop-installation) but in truth, I don't see what they have in common at all.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg How can this be a duplicate? It's about using the editor, not installing packages.

Comment: If by 'single window mode' you mean one window with tabs, I'm afraid it's not possible, since TeXShop doesn't implement that style of interface.

Comment: @alan-munn, that's not the interface I'm talking about. My computer is in French so it might not be called Single Window Mode in English, but I'll try to explain: If you go to the Window menu, there should be two options - something along the lines of "Use only one window" and another which is something like "Use separate windows." They are directly under the command which can be activated by ⌘1. The mode activated by "Use only one window" (or equivalent) is what I mean by Single Window Mode.

Comment: @mchenja Ah, ok, now I understand. In all my years of using TeXShop I've never noticed that.

Comment: PLEASE close-happy voters. This is **not** a duplicate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no way to set this as a default display mode. Initial attempts to allow it by Dick Koch, the developer of TeXShop, caused various problems and were abandoned.  At the present, this is therefore a very low priority feature request.

Comment: I love one window mode, every document I open I go into the menu and select this option. I wish that this would have higher priority.

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned this currently isn't possible.
However to make life a bit easier you can create a Mac Keyboard Shortcut.

```
System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts

Press the + button and enter the following.

Application: Texshop
Menu Title: Use One Window
Keyboard Shortcut: *enter your keyboard shortcut*
```

Now whenever you open a document all you need to press is your keyboard shortcut :]

Comment: Comment from user @Kane : shouldn't it be `Preview->Display Format->Single Page Keyboard Shortcut: your keyboard shortcut` ?

Comment: Nice suggestion!

Comment: Brilliant, life saver! @T.Verron: "Use One Window" worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found Patrick's solution to be a good workaround, but I think the exact question may have been misunderstood. The keyboard shortcut for what the questioner asks to do (putting preview in single page view) is as follows:

System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts

Press the + button and enter

Application: Texshop
Menu Title: Preview->Display Format->Single Page
Keyboard Shortcut: *your keyboard shortcut*

(I would have added this as a comment @Patrick, but it wouldn't let me since I just signed up to add comments here.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! If the system doesn't want you to comment, posting an answer as a work-around is not really acceptable, don't you think? In this situation, I think that you can suggest an edit even without any reputation, by clicking the `edit` button under the answer.