# xelatex problem with datetime

Tags: errors, xetex, datetime

I have a datetime problem if I try to compile my latex file. It is something with datetime, but I cant figured it out, what it is.

I have append the log

How Can solve the problem of solving the datetime issue?

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./CV - Thomas Bosch.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 21 languages loaded.
(../layout/header.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3unicode-data.def)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-patches.st
y
*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
* 
* Redefining document command \oldstylenums with arg. spec. 'm' on line 144.
*************************************************
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmss.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/xebabel.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngerman.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngermanb.ldf)
))

! LaTeX Error: File `datetime.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: q
```

Comment: You obviously don't have the sty, so install it -- or better the successor datetime2. http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime2

Comment: Your log suggests a cut-down TeX installation (the path has `basic`) in it, so suggesting you need to use `tlmg` to add packages by hand.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thx for the link. I have downloaded but dont no where but the included files in the zip file. Can you help? I'm using a Mac

Comment: Perhaps the answers to [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10252/how-do-i-add-a-sty-file-to-my-mactex-texshop-installation) might help.