# tex file compilable on windows but not on OSX

Tags: texstudio, mactex, mac

first time Mac user.
All my tex files (dissertation, CV, etc) compile fine on windows: texStudio + miktex. But the same files give errors on OSX: texStudio + macTex

There are numerous error messages, literally every line gives an error. So I doubt it is some particular command/package that causes the problem.

To see if it is the settings of texStudio in the OSX, I created a helloWorld document, and it compiled fine.

I know this description might be too general to give advice, but has anyone experienced similar thing? Thank you!

Comment: Show the error messages -- start with the first.

Comment: Also, if you take a hello world document from Windows and bring it to the Mac, does it compile? What's the simplest document you can edit down to that causes an error, and what's the error?

Answer (score 1):

The MacTeX package is 2GB+ and it is better to install the complete one. That is, unless you have major storage issues, in which case you may prefer the online TeX compilers. I had the exact problem when switching over from MiKTeX to TeXLive. I had to go through the pain of installing the missing packages one by one. It worked.

This involved checking the error codes for 'package not found' errors and installing those exact packages from the MiKTeX installation itself (copy-paste from the tex/latex/ directory).

Comment: Erh, this: "I had to go through the pain of installing the missing packages one by one." Does not make much sense, as TL installs everything (that is available to TL). So what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I mean whatever I require from MiKTeX that's not in TeXLive.

Comment: You might want to explain that in your answer. Not everyone know there is a difference in the available packages in MikTeX vs TL

Comment: Added the edit. One of such packages is fontspec.

Comment: erh, `fontspecd` **is** in TL. http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec

Comment: I still do not understand your edit. Exactly which packages do you need to copy from MikTeX?

Comment: A few of the thesis packages, including thesis.cls.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. It seems that the errors are caused by not-existing class or styles. TexStudio in Mac does not install on-the-fly as MikTex in Windows does. So I mannually put the class file in texmf/tex/latex/... And it solved the problem. Bad news is that all the error messages need looking into:(

Comment: Then you haven't installed full MacTeX. If you install it then all the packages will be there. You should not generally need to install packages manually, and if you do they should go into `~/Library/texmf`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10252/2693

Comment: Yes that's the right one but `res.cls` isn't part of TeX Live. So as long as you put it into the local texmf folder as I describe in the link you should be fine. Don't put stuff into `/usr/local/texlive...`

Comment: Thanks Alan. I came across the link before. Below is the sample tex file I used. And TexStudio said it cannot find the res.cls. The MACTEX I used is a 2GB+ .pkg file I downloaded. Is that the right installer?

    \documentclass[line, margin]{res}
     
    \begin{document}
    \name{Max Burstein}
    \address{1234 Herp Derp Lane \\ Rabble, FL 34343 \\ (516) 516-5165}
     
    \begin{resume}
     
    \end{resume}
    \end{document}

Comment: Because of the license of that class I do not think it is included in Texlive (MacTeX is TeXLive packed for Mac). It is also a very old class with no updates since 2001, might be a better idea to switch to a more modern class for writing resumes