# Install packages (.sty file) manually on TeXShop?

Tags: packages, installing

I'm using TeXShop on my Macbook. After I upgraded my system to El Captain, my TeXshop stopped typesetting. I reinstalled the complete version of MacTex 2015 again. It turned out that a package I used for many of my papers is missing.

It is a `.sty` file written by a friend so it is not on TeX Live. I tried some methods I found online, e.g. [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10252/how-do-i-add-a-sty-file-to-my-mactex-texshop-installation). But it does not work. I created `~/library/texmf` but TeXshop still cannot find the package. I remember that last time I installed that package, this method did not work for me, and I copied that `.sty` file into some other folder somewhere under `usr/...`

I also tried to use commands directly in terminal. But the new system on Mac totally forbids any change to `usr/...` and I just have no way to either use terminal or copy the file into a folder under `usr/...`

So, I would appreciate it if someone can help me out.

Comment: Welcome! `mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/<special-package>; mv <filename>.sty $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/<special-package>/`. Where `<filename>.sty` is the `.sty` file and `<special-package>` is the name of the package (without special characters, spaces etc. i.e. just letters and hyphens, if needed).

Comment: Even Apple have not gone quite so far as to banish the command line altogether. They have just decided to prevent you making changes to your own system which you own and they do not. Be that as it may, you do not need to make changes to `/usr`. You do need to use Terminal to run the above commands. But that should work fine.

Comment: Incidentally, you probably copied it to somewhere under `/usr/local`. If you wish, you can do that by using `sudo` and replacing `TEXMFHOME` with `TEXMFLOCAL`. This will also work fine. (`/usr/local` can be modified - only `/usr` and things other than `local` under `/usr` cannot.) If you do that, you also then need to run `sudo mktexlsr $(kpsewhich TEXMFLOCAL)`. This is not necessary for `TEXMFHOME`. [I assume that your distribution is installed, contrary to upstream's advice, with root privileges. Hence `sudo` is required.]

Comment: _Exactly_ where inside `~/Libarary/texmf` did you put the package? For LaTeX code, it needs to be inside `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex`, for example.

Comment: Thanks very much guys. I used the "make-local-texmf" app and successfully installed my package.

Comment: And I also figured out my initial problem. Here it is, which may help someone else; or it simply shows that I'm silly... If I go to "Finder-->Go-->Home", there is a folder "Library" there. And it turned out that this is not the "Library" folder people refer as "~/Library/texmf/tex/latex". So, it did not work if I create texmf there. The right path, at least for me, is "Finder-->Go-->Home-->Users-->(Your account name)", and there is a hidden folder "Library" folder over there. And if you create texmf there and follow all instructions, it works.

Comment: Which 'make-local-texmf' app?