# Software Needed to Run LawTeX on macOS Sierra and How to Install LawTeX

Tags: packages, installing

My iMac is running MacOS Sierra 10.12.6. I am planning to use LawTeX to typeset some law journal documents primarily using the templates in the LawTeX's examples folder. 
 1. I have located the current version of LaTeX on the LateX-project.org which is MacTeX-2017. The website also gives BasicTeX to download, based on my intended usage, (a) can I simply download the BasicTeX? (b) do I need to download the following MacTeXtras?

Extras: 
Software programs for bibliographies, the TeX Catalog Online (TCO), Editors & Front Ends, Equation Editors, Installers & Updaters, Scripts, and Spell Checkers. A "What's in Extras" document describing the applications, versions, licenses (where known) and click-able links for all of the software in the Extras Folder is available here.

Demos: 
Showcase items for ConTeXt, TeX, XeTeX.

Documentation: 
Information on Fonts; Sources for the WhatIsHere and WelcomeToMacTeX files, and a brief summary list of the Licenses for various applications included as Extras; plus information on "Starting Off".

(c) I have downloaded the LawTeX package from a sourceforge.net website with LawTeX-Doc by Mr. De Coro dated October 7, 2014. Is this LawTeX package the most updated for MacOS?

(d) After I install the LaTeX, how do I install LawTeX package into my system? I am not that familiar with using the terminal under MacOS.

Much appreciation for any suggestion or answer.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a link to the LawTeX repository. Otherwise nobody can tell you what you need. It will depend also on the `.tex` document you are trying to compile, which may use other things besides LawTeX not included in MacTeX.

Comment: Welcome, you have many questions. Most of them will be answered by reading some introductory material

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Here is the link to the LawTeX repository. https://sourceforge.net/projects/lawtex/files/. My application will be limited to the .tex examples inside the Samples Folder of the LawTex package.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely download the full MacTeX and *not* the BasicTeX if you are a beginner. With the full MacTeX you will get all the standard packages and will generally save yourself lots of trouble installing missing things.

The LawTeX package should go into your local `texmf` folder. See

- [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10252/2693)

for details on how to do this.

The LawTeX folder should go into

```
~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/
```

If you want the documentation to be found using `texdoc` (or from within TeXShop), you should also make a folder:

```
~/Library/texmf/doc/lawtex
```

and put the `lawtex-doc.pdf` file there.

LawTeX is a bit strange as citation systems go, because it does not use `bibtex` to process the citations but instead uses `makeindex`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the Make-local-texmf script (downloadable from above Alan Munn' s link "How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?").  The script automatically creates a folder "texmf" inside "~/Library" folder which can be accessed by using Go to Folder ~/Library and which is located under "Users" folder and grayed. Make sure exception for non apple download is allowed under System Preferences. Then LawTeX folder can be simply dragged into the within LaTeX folder.