# Beamer Installation

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

I am new to Latex especially with beamer... Now I have been trying to compile a file as shown but I got the error of Latex error: Beamerthemesharelatex.sty not found .. I had read instruction about downloading the beamer package and I downloaded it, but I do not understand the read me file at all, which files shall I copy and where to paste .. Please help

```
\documentclass{beamer}
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{times}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
  \boldmath

  \usetheme{Sharelatex}
  \usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4]{beamerposter}


  \title[Beamer Poster]{ShareLaTeX example of the beamerposter class}
  \author[sharelatexteam@sharelate.com]{ShareLaTeX Team}
  \institute[Sharelatex University]
  {The ShareLaTeX institute, Learn faculty}
  \date{\today}
  \logo{\includegraphics[height=7.5cm]{SharelatexLogo}}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{} 
    \vfill
    \begin{block}{\large Fontsizes}
      \centering
      {\tiny tiny}\par
      {\scriptsize scriptsize}\par
      {\footnotesize footnotesize}\par
      {\normalsize normalsize}\par
      ...
    \end{block}

    \end{block}
    \vfill
    \begin{columns}[t]
      \begin{column}{.30\linewidth}
        \begin{block}{Introduction}
          \begin{itemize}
          \item some items
          \item some items
          ...
          \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.48\linewidth}
        \begin{block}{Introduction}
          \begin{itemize}
          \item some items and $\alpha=\gamma, \sum_{i}$
          ...
          \end{itemize}
          $$\alpha=\gamma, \sum_{i}$$
        \end{block}
        ...

      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message says `beamerthemesharelatex.sty` is missing, not `beamer` itself. That file defines a theme, that in the template you use is chosen with `\usetheme{sharelatex}`.

(Note that this is case sensitive: if you have `\usetheme{sharelatex}` it looks for a file called `beamerthemesharelatex.sty`, while if you have `\usetheme{Sharelatex}` the file should be called `beamerthemeSharelatex.sty`.)

If you comment out/remove `\usetheme{sharelatex}` it will likely work, assuming `beamerposter` is installed (which it might well be). If you want to use that theme, then download the mentioned file from ShareLaTeX, it is for example a part of this template: https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/presentations/beamerposter---flow-multicolumn Place it in the same folder as your `.tex` file to make it available.

Regarding the code in your question, it has one `\end{block}` too many, which causes an error. Note at the start of the `frame` environment you have this:

```
\begin{block}{\large Fontsizes}
  \centering
  {\tiny tiny}\par
  {\scriptsize scriptsize}\par
  {\footnotesize footnotesize}\par
  {\normalsize normalsize}\par
  ...
\end{block}

\end{block} % <-- delete this
```

Remove the second `\end{block}`.

Comment: @ Torbjorn, thank you so much for your prompt reply.. However, I commented the line of the theme and still not working because of the frame, but I do understand what you have said... I am just wondering how to install the beamer into Texshop or the Beamerposter because I am gonna do a poster.. I would appericted your steps to guide me to install beamer poster .. Thanks again

Comment: @Refat_Gir Your problem is not about installation. `beamer` is installed, if it wasn't you would get an error saying "file `beamer.cls` not found" from `\documentclass{beamer}`. And if you get problems at the `frame` environment, then `beamerposter` must be installed as well, otherwise you would get an error about "file `beamerposter.sty` not found" at `\usepackage{beamerposter}`.

Comment: @Refat_Gir I didn't test your code before, but having done that I see that it does in fact not work. I'll see if I can figure it out, and update if I can.

Comment: @Refat_Gir You had an extra `\end{block}`, remove that and it works fine.

Comment: @ Torbjorn, thank you so much for your info. 
- For my curiosity I'd like to learn how to install those.
- I am gonna present a conference poster and I'd like to choose the best format, packages and so on.. would you mind suggesting me... because it s my first time with poster in Latex ... even I am not so good in Latex in general.. :).. Thanks,

Comment: @Refat_Gir I would suggest you ask a new question (if searching doesn't help), but you need to provide some more info when you do that, the editor (TeXshop in your case) is rather irrelevant actually. Did you install MacTeX? (If you installed the complete MacTeX, then you will have almost all common packages installed already.)  MacTeX has a program called TeX Live Utility that can be used to upgrade/install packages. For packages not available via the TL Utility, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10256