# Altering bst files in TeXshop

Tags: bibtex, installing

I'm trying to italicize journal article titles in my bibliography and so I've changed to code to include emphasize under the `FUNCTION {format.title}` section and removed the emphasize in the `FUNCTION {article}` section in my `unsrt.bst` file. However, when I compile, nothing changes and I'm convinced that there's a duplicate (possibly multiple) `unsrt.bst` files floating around. How do I check which file it's calling?

I looked around and people have mentioned to look in the `~/Library/texmf` directory and I'm not entirely sure if those directories are self-created as I can't find them at all.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) We kindly suggest you to show a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) on what you have worked so far, so we can help you further with your problem.

Comment: Do you know the `kpsewhich` command?

Comment: I've removed the [tag:texshop] tag, since this has nothing to do with TeXShop, which is an editor.

Answer (score 3):

You should never change the distribution versions of files directly. Instead make a copy of the file and **rename it**.

Then you can put it in your local `texmf` folder (or in the same directory as your source `.tex` file.).

See the following question for details on how to set up a local `texmf` folder, and where things should go. `.bst` files should go in `~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst` (on a Mac), or `~/texmf/bibtex/bst` on most Linux systems.  In that answer there is also a link to a script you can run to create a local `texmf` folder structure on a Mac. (I am the author.)

- [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10252/how-do-i-add-a-sty-file-to-my-mactex-texshop-installation)

To find out which file is actually being loaded in a particular compilation, you can look at the console output or the log file (in the case of the bibliography the `.blg` file.)

To find out in advance which file TeX (or associated programs) will find for a particular package, you can use the following command from the Terminal:

```
kpsewhich <filename>
```

e.g.

```
kpsewhich unsrt.bst
```

should return the following on a TL 2017 system. (In other years, the year will be different.)

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/base/unsrt.bst
```

Comment: +1, but note that `.bst` file are not read during the compilation of a `.tex` file.

Comment: @GuM I was using TeX here to mean "the programs of the distribution", but since you insist, I've made things more accurate. :)

Comment: Now the answer’s fine! :-)  I really think those nine words will help novice users.