# How to install the hmcpset package for LyX Mac with MacTex?

Tags: lyx, texlive, mac, mactex

I've been trying for several days to get this to work, but i haven't been successful yet. I'm new to latex and I don't have a very good idea of what I'm doing, which is why I'm using LyX.

I put the `hmcpset.cls` file in the directory `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/Max's classes`. I think the MacTex distribution uses TEX Live Utility for managing packages, so that's where I'm looking to find hmcpset. But `hmcpset` doesn't show up in available packages inside TEX LIVE.

Is there a way to let TEX Live know where I put a new `.cls` files?

Once TEX Live, or whatever the package manager is, knows where the `.cls` file is, will I be able to use the `hmpcpset` class in LyX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10256/36296 could be helpfull

Comment: Don't use folder (and file) names with spaces and curious chars in them.

Comment: Did you run `sudo mktexlsr` after installing the file(s)? That is needed so that the files are found.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run `texhash` in terminal and then in Lyx Tools > reconfigure.  Then restart Lyx.  Your packages should be visible.