# How do I install third-party packages in MacTeX?

Tags: packages, mactex

I would like to know how I can install third-party packages that are not included in the standard MacTeX distribution.

I am interested in using jecon.bst in particular.

The current situation is:

- The .bst file works fine when I put the file in the same folder as the main .tex file. I am using TeXShop.
- The manual of jecon.bst file suggests that I put the file in the folder where jplain.bst is located, and I did that. In addition to this, I copy pasted jecon folder into bibtex/bst folder as well. However the engine upbibtex cannot locate jecon.bst.
- [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10252/how-do-i-add-a-sty-file-to-my-mactex-texshop-installation)
  did not solve my problem. I could locate the texmf hidden folder without any problem, as I indicated above.

Is there anything else I have to do for upbibtex to recognize jecon.bst?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Normally, local additions which are not part of the distribution should be in your `texmf-local` folder, respecting the T.D.S. – namely, in `texmf-local/bibtex/bst` (creating the directories which do not exist if necessary).

Comment: Thank you for thoughtful advice. 
@Bernard I have tried texmf-local (I do not know whether the subfolders I created are appropriate).

Comment: @KJO I also 1) checked doppelgenger sort of things along with 4) avoid Japanese paths. I have little ability to check 2) for myself. I also browsed the link you gave me. 
Unfortunately, none has worked so far. 
I will get along via the most basic option -- placing the .bst file in the same folder as .tex file.

Comment: Some MacTeX users like to put their local additions instead into  `~/Library/texmf`. (This allows for different local configurations if there are multiple users for the computer.) Then your `.bst` file could go into `~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst/local`.

Comment: Use `kpsewhich -show-path=bst` to show the paths that are searched for .bst files. MacTeX does things slightly differently from vanilla TeX Live, for historical reasons.

Comment: I sincerely apologize. 
I simply did not know mktexlsr. When I ran it, TeX Live did recognize the .bst file. 
Many thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, I have to run mktexlsr.