# Add styles to MacTeX

Tags: installing, texmaker, mactex, styles

I am a new user of LaTeX and would like to use it for my Master's thesis. I would like to use the styles from Journal of Finance (cf. http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stanton/texintro/).

Unfortunately I dont' know how to install the .sty files in my MacTex/ I use TexMaker (what is the difference, where do you install?). 
The installation guides refer to `Library/texmf`, but this folder does not exist in my folder structure. 
I assume this is because of MacTex 2019 distribution and changes in folder structure (only `user/Library/texlive/2019/texmf-var/tedxdoc` or `user/Library/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/tfm...`)

Thanks in advance.

Similar question but they dont tackle my missing folder problem ([How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10252/how-do-i-add-a-sty-file-to-my-mactex-texshop-installation?answertab=active#tab-top))

Comment: Putting the files in your working directory should be all you have to do

Comment: I want to use the styles for several document and so it should be selectable as new document style without having it in each folder.

Comment: Then put it in `~/Library/texmf`. Use Alan Munn's script to create the directory structure: https://www.msu.edu/~amunn/latex/make-local-texmf.zip

Comment: Already tried the script and I receive the error: ```“make-local-texmf” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Bin.```.  There is no ```~/Library/texmf``` folder.

Comment: Try: `mkdir -p ~/Library/texmf/latex`, then copy all your packages there

Comment: Done, when I now compile to PDFLaTeX the test file I receive: ```! LaTeX Error: File `versionPO.sty' not found.Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter file name:! Emergency stop.<read > \usepackage```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te

Comment: This linked help. After setting up the folder structure like ```~Library/texmf/tex/latex/```, I don't receive the error. Quick question: I now receive the warning: ```You have requested package `versionPO',but the package provides `verbatim'.``` The versionPO is also a style which is in the folder (see website I linked in the question). Is this problematic?

Comment: @JosephWright see my earlier comment.