# How to let my TeXShop see new packages?

Tags: texshop, pgfornament

I am using TeXShop on macOS, where I want to use the package pgfornament. I downloaded the zip file from:
https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfornament?lang=en

From there I didn't really know where to go, as it seemed from looking around that I need to put the .sty file in my **(~/Library/texmf)** which I can not find. I found the library by Go -> Home in the finder, but there I only have TeX folder. I found an article with similar problem: [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10252/how-do-i-add-a-sty-file-to-my-mactex-texshop-installation)
But the application made by Alan Munn in the first answer is not working anymore and I do not have access to the link he gave.

I have tried different ways to make it work, all failed expect for when I have my .tex file in the same folder with the .sty and the .pgf files. The problem with that, there are different sets of .pgf files and I won't be able to access all at the same time, also I would have to repeat the process for each .tex I make (which I believe I can put it in a library for TexShop to always access).

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why don't you use TeX Live Utility? It  will automatically refresh  the file names database.

Comment: it is possible but tricky and unnecessary to install manually from ctan, simply let mactex/texlive install the package. (texshop is the editor you are using to write your files so not really involved here)

Comment: @Bernard, I have been seeing texlive but never really knew it was until now! It looks familiar to MiKTeX which I have but it didn't seem to do anything packages related.

Comment: TeX Live has a package manager, and TeX Live Utility is the version for MacOS, as far as I know (one of my friends uses it on his computer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pgfornament package is already part of TeX Live which is installed by MacTeX so there is nothing that you have to install. If you installed BasicTeX rather than MacTeX you should get TeX Live Utility, as mentioned above, and look under the packages tab where you can select and install missing packages.

Comment: I do have MacTex and just downloaded TeX Live Utility. When I search for pgfornament, I find two of them one is installed and the other is not. The not installed one is the one I am looking for, but non the less when I `\usepackage{pgfornament}` in my TeXShop; it gives me the same error: File `pgfornament.sty' is not found. It is also not clear to me how to install a not installed package with TeX Live.

Comment: Why the un-installed one? I think we need a minimal file that shows the failure. In Terminal run the command `kpsewhich pgfornament.sty` and it should return `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfornament/pgfornament.sty`.

Comment: This is what I got back: `/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/pgfornament/pgfornament.sty`. I have MiKTeX and I tried installing the package with it before, is that what it is saying? Also I just tried `\usepackage{pgfornament}` and it's working fine.

Comment: Slightly different question, looking around I found that TeX Live is better than MiKTeX in the long run. So if I uninstalled MiKTeX, would the `pgfornament` package stop working, or it wouldn't be affected?

Comment: So you didn’t install MacTeX. The MacTeX installer package installs a full TeX Live 2020. It can be updated to the latest versions packages by using TeX Live Utility. You may have to remove MikTeX to keep from having interference problems between the two distributions.

Comment: I have been using TeXShop for few months now, doing several school projects with it. Doesn't that mean I have MacTeX installed? I didn't have any problems with it except for the `pgfornament` package, so maybe after installing TeX Live Utility and updating all packages the `pgfornament` package started working.

Comment: What does `which pdflatex` executed in Terminal return?

Comment: It returns: `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex`

Comment: That looks ok. Are you saying everything is working now?

Comment: Yeah everything is working fine so far. Thank you a lot for helping and following up with me!