# mystyle.sty not found

Tags: packages, mactex

I created a .sty file that includes many different packages and new commands that I already use.  I put mystyle.sty file here:

/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mystyle/mystyle.sty

Unfortunately, when I try to `\usepackage{mystyle}`, the file is not found. I try to use TexMaker and TexShop and run the package, but to no avail.

What am I missing?  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Nick

Comment: For custom packages, I would recommend putting them in your home texmf tree, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te

Comment: If you put your style file in the `texmf-dist` path you'd have to rebuild the ls-R files (index files). But you should consider putting your own style files not into the dist-folder, but into your texmf-home (that is usually `~/texmf`) therein create `tex/latex/mystyle/` and put your style file in that folder. The advantage is, that you don't have to rebuild the index files.

Comment: ... another advantage of using the home texmf tree is that it will survive updates. Your package will still be there if you upgrade from texlive 2022 to 2023

Comment: And for a more Mac specific answer see: [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10252/)

Comment: I have three ~/texmf they are ~/texmf-dist, ~/texmf-config, and ~/texmf-var I don't have ~/texmf-home.

Comment: Where did you install TeX? Your question suggests you have installed into `/usr/local/texlive`. Your last comment suggests you've installed into your home directory. Those directories are not standard ones to find in your home. What does `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMF` give and how did you install TeX?