# Template only working on overleaf

Tags: texmaker, templates, books

when i try to run a template from overelaf

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,violet]{bbe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Title}
    \section{Title}
    \begin{definition}
    Hello world
    \end{definition}
    \begin{remark}
    This is remark
    \end{remark}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

it is not working on my PC, since i get the error "! LaTeX Error: File `bbe.cls' not found.
Type X to quit or  to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)
Enter file name:
! Emergency stop."

But its working fine, when i run it on overleaf.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What's your question?

Comment: @Mico: i dont now the problem... why isnt it working?

Comment: Error message told you that `bbe` document class can not be found. Meaning, that you not have installed in your LaTeX distro. Unfortunately this is proprietary style not available on CTAN,

Comment: @zarko: so is there a possible solution, when its not reachable on CTAN?

Comment: Of course. Find Overleaf "bbe Book Template" by google, open it, than select  `bbe.cls`,  copy its code to your editor and than store to your working directory (where you have your document) or  if you use in some other directory/map to some other place, where LaTeX can find it. In later case you also need to refresh file name database.

Comment: If you use Linux or MacOS see, e.g., [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016) or [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10252) For MiKTeX see [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063).

Comment: Did you download your project from overleaf? if so I would expect that it has all required files including the bbe.cls file in the right place to work with  the document

Comment: @fullspeed, Davids suggestion to download it of course works: the .zip file contains all you need. // And, as you will see, this class is based on the book-class ...

Answer (score 0):

The overleaf template will have made a project that contained the `bbe.cls` file, so to use a local tex installation you should just need to download the project and extract the files from teh zip archive, which will all be in teh correct relative locations to use with tex. Do not just download your main document file.