# Installing a class

Tags: packages, installing, document-classes

I created a new class file to use.

I have put the .cls file in the same directory as the original cls files (report, book etc) and im 100% sure the names match.

The directory for me is:

`C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\base`

But still, when compiling it says:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `myclass.cls' not found.
```

What am i doing wrong here? (sorry for being such a noob)

In my texteditor i use:

```
\documentclass[12pt,%
               %draft,%
               a4paper]{myclass}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a duplicate of the following questions:

- [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/2693)
- [How to have local package override default package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8357/2693)

The basic answer is you should never put your own packages or classes in the main directories of your TeX distribution. You should always put them into a local directory. Consult the accepted answers to these questions for more details of how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Every own created package and class should go into a local tree, which is supported by all TeX distributions. For MiKTeX read the [MiKTeX documentation](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/localadditions.html), section "Register a user-managed TEXMF directory". It shows how a local tree can be created, if not already present.

Comment: In Miktex, we can easily register our own packages/classes that are saved in any sub directory of `tex\latex` (no matter where we put the `tex\latex` directory) to the LaTeX system as explained in your link above. How to do the same thing in TeX Live?

Answer (score 4):

A quick fix is to just put the .cls file next to the .tex file you're compiling (ie. in the same directory).

Perhaps this is not a permanent enough solution for you (eg. if you're going to use this class file in many documents), but this is how I use IEEE's & OSA's journal class files (where once every few years at most I need to use a particular class file).  This has the added benefit of your LaTeX document's directory being self-contained - it should compile on any other LaTeX system without needing any additional installation - important for submitting a journal paper - not sure about your case.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thank you for the help. For complete newbies like me, here is [a short tutorial](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2011/03/27/how-to-write-a-latex-class-file-and-design-your-own-cv.html) on what is a class file and how to actually use one.

Answer (score 2):

- I recommend to put your class file into a dedicated directory.
- After copying the class into your texmf directory structure, refresh TeX's file name database. In MiKTeX, open MiKTeX Options/ Settings and click the button "Refresh FNDB", or run `mktexlsr` (or `texhash` in some distributions) at the command prompt.

Comment: I put it in the directory with the other classes. What u mean with a dedicated directory? 

I did refresh the database but didnt help.

Comment: @Toroo: I mean: don't mix your own files with distribution files. What if you update to MiKTeX 2.9 but your class remains in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\base`?