# TexLive (Ubuntu): Installing a new class

Tags: document-classes

I have a class file I have put in my local texmf directory (.texmf/tex/latex/classdir) and run `sudo texhash` but I am still getting a build error saying that my class file cannot be found. I have gone through the following posts to no avail

[Installing a class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10498/installing-a-class)

[How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows)

and the read me hasn't been much help either

https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-460006

(I'm on a brand new installation of texlive fyi)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `pdflatex: /usr/bin/pdflatex /usr/share/man/man1/pdflatex.1.gz`

Comment: `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)`

Comment: from repo
`sudo apt install texlive*`

Comment: I added sudo because I got this when I didn't

`texhash: /usr/local/share/texmf: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /var/lib/texmf: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /var/lib/texmf: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /var/lib/texmf: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: Done.
`

Comment: texhash .texmf succeeded just now though. Still getting a compile error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84361/discussion-between-rhythmink-and-sigur).

Comment: Are the file and every local directory it’s under world-readable?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get things working by putting my class file in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex` which isn't `texmf-local` obviously but at least things are working. If someone else knows how to find that folder/create it since it doesn't seem to exist for me I'd love to know. For others having a similar issue using the directory above should work and then just use `texhash`.