# How to install tkz-2d in TeXLive 2010?

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, installing, tkz-collection

How to install tkz-2d in TeXLive 2010?
My directory is /usr/local/texlive/2010 but i do not know which folder to place and even how to active.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `tkz-2d` package has been replaced by the `tkz-euclide` package.  You should download the [latest version](http://altermundus.fr/downloads/packages/tkz.zip).  When you unzip the folder you can move the contents to the the latex folder of your local texmf folder.  See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/how-to-have-local-package-overide-default-package/8359#8359) for more details on how to set up your local folder, and where it is located.