# Mypackage on Macbook Pro

Tags: packages, installing, mac

I created a `mypackage.sty` file using all the packages, new-commands, other command shortcuts. Instead of loading packages I just load `mypackage` which mostly contains everything for my needs.

I recently switched from a Linux machine to a Macbook.
Where should I keep the mypackage files in OS X?

Comment: What are mypackage files? I never heard of them and Google doesn't enlighten me.

Comment: While it may be necessary at times to create a new tag (or even several ones) when asking a question, it seems highly unlikely that *no* existing tag is applicable to this question.

Comment: I created a .sty file using all the packages, new-commands, other command shortcuts. Instead of loading packages I just load mypackage which mostly contains everything for my needs. Does this help?

Comment: @Aku: I rewrote the question to add the info from your comment. I hope this is okay and I understood your problem correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MacTex will automatically search for files in your "personal" part of the TeX directory tree system. Assuming your userid on your Mac system is "aku", the root of this personal part would be at `/Users/aku/Library/texmf`. MacTeX's installation routine should have already created this folder -- as well as several subfolders such as `tex`, `bibtex`, and probably a few others -- at the time it set up all other folders. Since your aim is to store the file `mypackage.sty` in a texlive/mactex-compliant way, I suggest you put it in the folder

```
/Users/aku/Library/texmf/tex/latex/mypackage
```

The folder `mypackage` will need to be created by you, obviously, before you can save  the file `mypackage.sty` in it. Because you'll probably be installing other packages as well in your personal part of the TeX directory tree over time, it's advisable (but it's not required!) to create separate folders for each LaTeX package. Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 4):

You can put it into the same places as under Linux: either in the same directory as the .tex file or into the local texmf tree, which is under `~/Library/texmf` in OS X (so you'd put the file in `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex`, see also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/how-to-have-local-package-overide-default-package/8359#8359)).