# LaTeX for Mac (lion) 2011 - how to add cls file?

Tags: installing, mactex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a .sty file to my TeXShop installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10252/how-do-i-add-a-sty-file-to-my-texshop-installation)

I'm trying to get into LaTeX and have to use a publisher provided cls file (and some tex and bst files) and try to use them with my LaTeX installation. I have the latest version of LaTeX and use texmaker as editor.

I tried to google for advise how to do that but its either confusing or it seems that things changed in lion/2011.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10252/how-do-i-add-a-sty-file-to-my-texshop-installation and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/how-to-have-local-package-overide-default-package/8359#8359

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from StackExchange. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files