# How to install Beamer in Mac OS X lion?

Tags: beamer, installing, mactex, themes

I am brand new to LaTeX, and needed `beamer` package for my PowerPoint presentation.

How do I install it? I have read something like this: http://www.arthurkoziel.com/2008/06/02/how-to-install-latex-beamer-for-tex-live-on-mac-os-x/

tried in the terminal, still get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `beamerthemeumbc3.sty' not found.
```

I think I am doing something wrong about my directory?  I have dragged beamer into TeX folder, which is inside Applications.

Hopefully someone can tell me the commands to type in terminal?

Comment: Well, `beamer` should have been included with your TeX installation. Are you not using TeXlive/MacTeX 2011?

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen I am using MacTex 2011.  The "What Is installed"pdf says I will have 6 subpackages: TexLive 2011, GUI-Applications, Ghostscript-9.02, ImageMagick-Convert-6.6.9, Latin-Modern-Fonts, Tex-Gyre-Fonts.

Comment: You make a mistake, TeX doesn't search inside TeX folder of the folder Applications. You need to place it in the library folder. The library folder is invisible but you can access it with Command Shift G and ~/library.

Comment: The link you posted is entirely irrelevant if you are using a MacTeX distribution (it's about MacPorts). See [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10252/2693) and [How to have local package override default package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/how-to-have-local-package-overide-default-package/8359#8359)

Comment: `A PowerPoint presentation`! Why don't you simply use the word "slides", "presentation", "slideshows", or even "overheads", "deck", "preso",  "foils", "filmstrips" ? Why would you use a branded name for such a common thing? Especially when they are not going to be produced by PowerPoint… You could call them "Beamer Presentation" `;-)`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to download the UMBC themes, as described in [Werner's response from April 17](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52206/14667).

The readme included with the UBMC themes is not very explicit:

1. Unzip the archive
   You get a folder `Beamer`, rename it to `UMBC`
2. In the menu choice **Go**, choose **Go to Folder** or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>G</kbd> and type `~/Library`
3. If you have a folder named `texmf`, open it or if not create it.
4. Inside if you have a folder named `tex`, open it or create it.
5. Now, inside if you have a folder named `latex`, open it or create it.
6. Finally: Put the `UMBC` folder inside the `latex` folder. That's all.

Here an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{umbc4}    
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Overlaying declarations and graphics}

\begin{theorem}<1->
Every finite distributive lattice can be embedded in a boolean lattice.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}<3->
Use join-irreducible elements.
\end{proof}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: just did what you said, still get the error, it looks like this: (/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/inner/beamerinnerth
emedefault.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/outer/beamerouterth
emedefault.sty)))

! LaTeX Error: File `beamerthemeumbc3.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:

Comment: Can you give a MWE ? `beamerthemeumbc3.sty` is in the themes folder (see Werner's answer ?) do you have the same folder ?

Comment: Do you have change something in the  texmf.cnf file ? Do you have the texmf folder inside you library ? You can run `texhash` in your terminal but normally it's not necessary. Another possibility is to place beamerthemeumbc3.sty in the same folder of your main file but it's not very elegant.

Comment: In my log I have this :`(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/outer/beamerouterthemedefault.sty))) (/Users/ego/Library/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/themes/theme/beamerthemeumbc4.sty` . You can see that after `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes`  tex searches inside  `/Users/ego/Library/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/themes/theme`

Comment: As Altermundus wrote, your beamer theme files must be placed within the folder ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex, not in the /usr... folder.

Comment: @Frédéric, What are the commands for installing in terminal?  I should be THAT hard, apparently, people have strong disagreements, I thought it should be a piece of cake for the experts.

Comment: @Altermundus what is MWE?  PLEASE KEEP IN MIND, I AM A NOOOB!!

Comment: @Altermundus My personal thanks to you, this direction is quick and simple!

Comment: @kulimer If you don't have a local `texmf` folder, you can use my make-local-texmf script available here: [make-local-texmf](https://www.msu.edu/~amunn/latex/make-local-texmf.zip). Run this script, and then follow Altermundus' instructions about where to put the UMBC folder.

Comment: All of this to get a beamer theme that is a ripoff from PowerPoint 2003? `:-D`

Answer (score 3):

The [UMBC themes](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~rostamia/beamer/quickstart-Z-H-8.html#node_sec_8) are not shipped with [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) and therefore do not form part of the basic distribution. You need to [downloaded these](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~rostamia/beamer/beamer-umbc.tar.gz) and install them separately. There's also a [README](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~rostamia/beamer/quickstart-Z-H-8.html#node_sec_8) that describes the process of parallel installation with `beamer`:

```
CONTENTS:

Here is the contents of the archive, shown as a directory tree:

beamer
|-- beamer-umbc.readme
`-- themes
    |-- inner
    |   |-- beamerinnerthemeumbcboxes.sty
    |   `-- beamerinnerthemeumbctribullets.sty
    |-- outer
    |   `-- beamerouterthemeumbcfootline.sty
    `-- theme
        |-- beamerthemeumbc1.sty
        |-- beamerthemeumbc2.sty
        |-- beamerthemeumbc3.sty
        `-- beamerthemeumbc4.sty

To install, just unpack and merge the archive into your existing
beamer directory tree.

You may need to run texhash to make your TeX installation aware of
the new files.
```

Following the above approach requests you to store the new themes in

```
/usr/local/texlive/2011/...
```

It is advisable to store this information in your local `~/Library/texmf/` folder rather, and avoid interfering with the TDS (TeX's Directory Structure).

Comment: how do you "archive into your existing beamer directory tree"?  and how do I texhash?  btw, is the link I posted not right?  I thought that was it.  This thing can't be THAT hard, right?

Comment: @kulimer: The link you posted refers to `beamer` installation. However, `beamer` comes with a number of themes (what things look like; see, for example, the [`beamer` theme matrix](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/)), and these themes can be developed by independent individuals. You should find your MacTeX 2011 folder (perhaps in Applications?). Inside is the so-called TDS (TeX Directory Structure). There you'll find the `beamer` folder `.../tex/latex/beamer/` where you'll see the folders listed above. `texhash` should be run from the terminal - it updates links to new installs.

Comment: @Werner This is *not* really the best way to put local additions. For most users it makes the most sense to put local additions into `~/texmf` or for Mac `~/Library/texmf`. Then you don't have to run `texhash` etc.  Also there is no "MacTeX 2011" folder.  MacTeX is simply a standard TeXLive installation with some niceties added for the Mac, mainly some standard GUI apps (TeXShop, BibDesk etc.) and a control panel for switching between multiple distributions.  But the distribution itself is in `/usr/local/texlive/<year>` just like any other TeXLive distribution, which you shouldn't mess with.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Sure. I've added a minor mention of this in my answer. It's just that I rarely meddle with the TDS and followed the README's suggestion. Thanks for keeping me on the straight-and-narrow.

Comment: I would make the recommendation stronger.  You simply shouldn't install anything in `/usr/local/texlive/<year>` *ever*. So the README advice is simply wrong.